# Is there a standard Java NonNullable<T> generic, and if not, why not?

Tags: java, generics, null, nullpointerexception, non-nullable

The problem with annotations such as `@NotNull/@NonNull` is that they aren't enforced at runtime.  I want to do something like the following:

```
class Foo {
  String nullable_string;
  final NonNullable<String> nn_string = new NonNullable<String>();
  ...
  public void mutate(String arg) {
    mutable_string = arg;  // arg could be null
    nn_string.set(arg);    // throws NullPointerException for me if arg is null.
  }
  ...
}
```

Does a standard `NonNullable<T>` generic exist somewhere, and if not, is there a reason it's a bad idea?

Comment: What would you expect from a NonNullable generic like that. It still extends Object in it's core; and every Object can reference null. No matter how NonNullable is build; I can still do `NonNullable nn = null;`

Comment: @Yhn: The point of such a class wouldn't be to ensure that a reference of type `NonNullable` could never be `null` but to ensure that it doesn't _contain_ `null`. That said, a `NonNullable` reference shouldn't ever be `null`, and that can be ensured by things like assigning an instance to a `final` field like in the example.

Comment: See JSR 305 status: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2289694/what-is-the-status-of-jsr-305

Comment: I mostly use `import javax.annotation.xxx`

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure that it does not exist. However you can built your own:

```
public class NonNullable<T> {

    private T element;

    public void set(T element) {
        if (element == null)
            throw new NullPointerException("Parameter was null!");
        else
            this.element = element;
    }

}
```

Comment: Building my own is definitely the direction I'm currently leaning.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to use a special wrapper class for that. If you don't want to allow something to be `null`, ensure it isn't `null` the moment it's given to you with a check. You can do this with standard Java:

```
if (arg == null)
  throw new NullPointerException();
this.string = arg;
```

Or with [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com), you can use the [Preconditions](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release09/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Preconditions.html) class to simplify it to:

```
this.string = checkNotNull(arg); // using static import
```

In r10 of Guava, coming sometime before too long, you could also use an [Optional<T>](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Optional.html) (immutable) or a [Holder<T>](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Holder.html) (mutable). These aren't necessarily exactly what you're looking for since they are both allowed to be "absent" (holding no value), but neither may ever contain `null`. `Holder` in particular seems like it could work for the scenario in your example, since you don't show it being initialized with any value (it isn't given any `String` when it's created, so it must initially be absent). Its `set` method throws `NullPointerException` if given `null`, just like you want.

```
final Holder<String> stringHolder = Holder.absent(); // nothing at first

public void mutate(String arg) {
  stringHolder.set(arg);
}
```

When using a `Holder` or `Optional`, you should generally check that it `isPresent()` before calling `get()` since it'll throw `IllegalStateException` if absent. Alternatively you can use the `or` method:

```
String definitelyNotNull = stringHolder.or("default");
```

Comment: You should throw `IllegalArgumentException` instead of `NullPointerException` if null is not allowed. Since it's an illegal argument, `IllegalArgumentException` is the appropriate exception.

Comment: @Steve: There are two camps on that, but the general consensus among Java programmers I know of is that `NullPointerException` is what should be thrown when an argument is `null` because it is the more specific exception in that case.

Comment: Yup, looks like `IllegalArgumentException` vs `NullPointerException` is is heavily debated http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3881/illegalargumentexception-or-nullpointerexception-for-a-null-parameter

Comment: The wrapper class prevents the code duplication implicit in that arg check you wrote out, and ensures that if the value is set in multiple places in the class implementation, any null is caught.

Holder looks like about the right concept, but we're not using Guava.

And you're right, "absent" is clearly a concept that NonNullable has to have to work if it can be created without an argument.

Comment: @ColinD, are you serious? It would be beneficial to specify non-nullity in the interface - therefore, prior to calling the function, at parameter creation the check is already enforced. Fail early? Annotiations are not enforced (nullability difficult to determine at compile time), and we don't want to duplicate code in the function bodies. The need seems **very** obvious to me. I'm surprised that java does not have such a type.

Answer (score 0):

IntelliJ has [@NotNull and @Nullable annotations](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/nullable-and-notnull-annotations.html).  It uses static checks in the IDE and byte-code instrumentation to perform the checks at runtime.  You could also instrument runtime checks as well.

Answer (score -4):

What about:

```
NonNullable<?>
```