# Is this class Immutable or mutable

Tags: scala

Is the below Scala class is mutable or immutable?

I believe that its immutable as I can't edit the variables or access them once its created but whats making me doubt myself is the fact that it returns the current instance of a variable using its functions. It also does not have final in front of it which is further making me doubt myself.

```
class person(name:String, dob:String){
  def getName = name
  def getDob = dob
  def display() = {
    println("Name "+name+" dob: "+dob)
  }
}
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a misconception with the term *Immutable*:

> I believe that its immutable as I can't edit the variables or access
>   them once its created

That's the definition of a *private* thing (method, variable, ...). Immutability refers to the fact that you cannot *mutate* state, that is, **you can't change the value of something unless you create a new instance of it**.

Let's see it with an example:

```
trait Foo{
  def myMutableValue: Int
}

class Clazz extends Foo{

  var myMutableValue = 1

  def changeState(): Int = {
    myMutableValue += 1
    myMutableValue
  }
}

val bar = new Clazz

bar.changeState() // myMutableValue = 2
bar.changeState() // myMutableValue = 3
bar.changeState() // myMutableValue = 4

bar.myMutableValue // myMutableValue = 4
```

With that example, in your **instance** of `Clazz` (`bar`) you're changing the state of a class attribute, in this case `myMutableValue` is changing its value every time I invoke `changeState`.
Please note that the class is public by default and `changeState` is also public and that doesn't means that is immutable.

Now, let's see an immutable approach:

```
trait Foo{
  def myMutableValue: Int
}

class Clazz extends Foo{

  val myMutableValue = 1

  def changeState(): Int = myMutableValue + 1
}

val instance = new Clazz

instance.changeState() // myMutableValue = 2
instance.changeState() // myMutableValue = 2
instance.changeState() // myMutableValue = 2

instance.myMutableValue // 1
```

With this approach, every call to `changeState` will evaluate to 2, no matter how many times I call the function. That is, because we're dealing with an immutable value (`val myMutableValue = 1`). Every invocation of `changeState` will perform the evaluation and return a copy of that value. You're not modifying in any way the value of `myMutableValue`.

Please take a look to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279507/what-is-meant-by-immutable) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4437373/use-of-def-val-and-var-in-scala).

Also, please take a look at your code, you have some errors:

- By convention, class name should be capitalized (`Person` instead of `person`).
- You **don't need to reassign your class values with `def`** (`def getName`and `def getDob`). You can use class values as is.

Lastly:

> It also does not have final in front of it which is further making me
>   doubt myself.

Again, you're talking about different things. `final`, as in Java, is a modifier to prevent your class to be `extended`. <strike>It doesn't relate in any way to immutability</strike> In adition, if you want to prevent mutability in your subclass you have to make all their members `final` ([see this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11335866/478030)).
Since your example is coded in Scala you have all the tools that the language itself offers at your disposal (e.g. `val`, `sealed`, `final`)

Please note that I've used a `trait` to explain the possible use of `def`.

**EDIT: [about `final` modifier and immutability](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24911800/478030)**

**Thanks to @Silvio Mayolo and @puhlen for the comments and clarification about `final`**

Comment: `final` in Java can also be used before a variable to mean something close to what Scala's `val` means, so it does relate to immutability. It just isn't in Scala.

Comment: `final` does relate to immutability, if not directly.  The problem with a non-final class is that one can create a subclass and override the members to make them mutable.  Thanks to polymorphic, this can make you think you have an immutible class but actually be working with a mutable subclass.