# Can't find @Nullable inside javax.annotation.*

Tags: java, annotations, nullpointerexception, nullable, null-pointer

I want use `@Nullable`  annotation to  eliminate `NullPointerExceptions`.
I found some tutorials on the net, I noticed that this annotation comes from the package `javax.annotation.Nullable`;
but when I import it a compilation error is generated: cannot find symbol

Answer (score 207, accepted):

You need to include a jar that this class exists in.  You can find it [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.findbugs/jsr305)

If using Maven, you can add the following dependency declaration:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.code.findbugs</groupId>
  <artifactId>jsr305</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

and for Gradle:

```
dependencies {
  testImplementation 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.2'
}
```

Comment: Why is Google (especially its findbugs artifact) providing types that belong to the `javax` package? Isn't there an artifact with a `javax`-prefixed groupId that provides this type?

Comment: @AndrewSwan it seems that the author chose the groupId of `com.google.code.findbugs` because it was being hosted on Google's code hosting solution

Comment: Google-findbugs is the reference implementation of the jsr305, thus they are kind of allowed to use the javax-packageName I guess.

Comment: Still relevant for swagger generator

Comment: I am receiving this error since I upgraded my IntelliJ. damn it.

Comment: Same issue here, have you found a solution @MehrajMalik?

Comment: Why is this not part of the foundation classes in the JDK?  For something that's inside of a foundation package, not external dependencies should be required.  What a PITA.

Answer (score 42):

The artifact has been moved from `net.sourceforge.findbugs` to

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.code.findbugs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsr305</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 31):

If you are using Gradle, you could include the dependency like this:

```groovy
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'com.google.code.findbugs', name: 'jsr305', version: '3.0.0'
}
```

Comment: I tried , and got error: Could not find method compile() for arguments [{group=com.google.code.findbugs, name=jsr305, version=3.0.0}] on org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler_Decorated@7b35fdf2.

Comment: @kamal with the above example, it is generally assuming you have applied the `'java'` (or other) plugin that has already created the [`compile` configuration](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#sec:java_plugin_and_dependency_management).

Comment: Unable to import javax.annotation.Nullable; I have jsr250-api-1.0.jar in my classpath. I even tried updating maven pom `<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.code.findbugs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsr305</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>`  Eclipse gave errors: Missing artifact `com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:3.0.0

Failure to transfer com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:3.0.0`

Comment: It finally worked jsr305-3.0.1.jar - some eclipse cp issue. Yes finally it compiles after external jar import into eclipse

Comment: Because the jar is not needed at runtime, use `compileOnly group...` instead of just `compile group...`

Comment: But is it really *not* needed at runtime? The RetentionPolicy of the @Nullable annotation is set to RUNTIME after all. As the jsr305.jar only includes annotations / interfac-defs the impact on your bundled jar is negligible.

Answer (score 19):

[JSR-305](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=305) is a "Java Specification Request" to extend the specification. `@Nullable` etc. were part of it; however it appears to be "dormant" (or frozen) ever since ([See this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2289694/what-is-the-status-of-jsr-305)). So to use these annotations, you have to add the library yourself.

[FindBugs](https://github.com/findbugsproject/findbugs) was renamed to [SpotBugs](https://github.com/spotbugs/spotbugs) and is being developed under that name.

For maven this is the *current* **annotation-only** dependency (other integrations [here](https://github.com/spotbugs/spotbugs#using-spotbugs)):

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.github.spotbugs</groupId>
  <artifactId>spotbugs-annotations</artifactId>
  <version>4.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

If you wish to use the full plugin, refer to the documentation of SpotBugs.

Comment: The `spotbugs-annotations` module has a compile dependency `<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.code.findbugs</groupId>
  <artifactId>jsr305</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.2</version>
</dependency>`, see https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.spotbugs/spotbugs-annotations/4.7.1 . Thus, if you need only the `@Nullable`, it is better to use directly the google findbugs dependency.

Answer (score 8):

In case someone has this while trying to compile an Android project, there is an alternative Nullable implementation in `android.support.annotation.Nullable`. So take care which package you've referenced in your `import`s.

Answer (score 5):

If anyone has this issue when building a Maven project created in IntelliJ IDEA externally, I used the following dependency instead of the answer:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jetbrains</groupId>
  <artifactId>annotations</artifactId>
  <version>15.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Using this will allow the project to build on IntelliJ IDEA and by itself using Maven.

You can find it [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jetbrains/annotations/15.0).

Comment: beware that `org.jetbrains:annotations:15.0` provides `@org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable` not `@javax.annotation.Generated`. This could be a problem in case you use some code generators as `openapi-generator-maven-plugin`.

Answer (score 4):

you can add latest version of this by adding following line inside your gradle.build.

```
implementation group: 'com.google.code.findbugs', name: 'jsr305', version: '3.0.2'
```

Answer (score 2):

I am using Guava which has annotation included:

(Gradle code )

```
compile 'com.google.guava:guava:23.4-jre'
```

Comment: Including Guava for just for this would be overkill, and to be avoided due to their poor versioning and tendency to make backwards-incompatible changes.

Comment: @Matthew Read  Guava shouldn't be avoided. There are features that aren't in plain Java - immutable collections(well it is in java >=9, but this one is better), mapMakers, splitters ....and so on. I think that adding guava brings good stuff. Maybe it is overkill just for this, but still it is better than using "findbugs"or "jetbrains" annotations.

Comment: I agree that Guava can be useful for other things, but that doesn't mean that it makes sense to bring in a large library for something tiny.  `com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305` is named poorly, but it is the official reference implementation.

Answer (score 1):

In the case of Android projects, you can fix this error by changing the project/module gradle file (build.gradle) as follows:

```
dependencies { implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:24.2.0' }
```

For more informations, please refer [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/annotations).

Answer (score 1):

For gradle build I used `compile('com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.2')` .
In case of test can use `testCompile('com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.2')`.