# how to query a combination of list id and interval spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

is there any way i can combine query with one more list teacher id , if list null i query only with time , if not null i will combine with id in list pls can someone help me ?

```
@Query(
        value = "select i.start_time, i.end_time, i.duration_time, s.subject_class_name, u.name as teacher_name," +
        " dc.name as class_room_name, ts.name as subject_name, tsc.total_time as total_time_subject_class," +
        "  i.teacher_context_type, i.teacher_id, s.subject_class_id" +
        " from tbl_attendance_sheet as s inner join tbl_attendance_instance as i on s.id = i.attendance_sheet_id " +
        " left join phong_hoc dc on i.class_id = dc.id " +
        " left join lms_user  u on u.id = i.teacher_user_id " +
        " left join tbl_subject_class as tsc on tsc.id = s.subject_class_id " +
        " left join tbl_subject as ts on ts.id = tsc.subject_id" +
        " where " +
        " ( " +
        " ((:start_time >= i.start_time and :start_time <= i.end_time) " +
        " or (i.start_time <= :end_time and :end_time <= i.end_time) or " +
        " (:start_time < i.start_time and :end_time > i.end_time)) " +
        " ) ",
        nativeQuery = true
    )
    List<Tuple> getAllDetailTeacherCheckOn(
        @Param("start_time") LocalDateTime startTime,
        @Param("end_time") LocalDateTime endTime
    );
```

I tried using ( case when :teacher_ids is null then true else i.teacher_id in :teacher_ids end ) " but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check that a List parameter is null in a Spring data JPA query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54026900/check-that-a-list-parameter-is-null-in-a-spring-data-jpa-query)

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is add an "AND" statement to your query that checks if there are matches in the list OR if the list is null.
Would look something like that:

`AND ((i.teacher_id in (:teacher_ids)) OR ((:teacher_ids) is null))`