# JPA Repository findAll with optional fields

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I have a controller try to search with optional field.
The JPA entity class is defined as:

```java
package demo;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
public class UploadFile {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private int id;
  private String name;

  public UploadFile() {
  }

  public UploadFile(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public int getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "UploadFile{" +
        "id=" + id +
        ", name='" + name + '\'' +
        '}';
  }

}
```

The controller is defined in the following code:

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/searchFile", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody
List<UploadFile> searchFile(@RequestParam("id") Optional<Integer> id, @RequestParam("name") Optional<String> name) {
    UploadFile newFile = new UploadFile();
    if (id.isPresent()) {
        newFile.setId(id.get());
    }
    if (name.isPresent()) {
        newFile.setName(name.get());
    }
    System.out.println("new File: " + newFile);

    //uploadFileRepository is a JpaRepository Class
    return List<UploadFile> files = uploadFileRepository.findAll(Example.of(newFile));
}
```

The database has one record:

```
ID      NAME    SIZE    TYPE  
1       index   111     html
```

When '/searchFile?id=1' hits server, the console prints:

```
new File: UploadFile{id=1, name='null'}
```

The http returns an empty array:

I want the `/searchFile?id=1` to return the record with id 1,
and also `/searchFile?name=index` to return the record with id 1 too.

Is there anything I did wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Your code looks good, the problem must be somewhere else. include the `UploadFile` class to your question.

Comment: @sh977218, can you add generated query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you cannot use the `example` to find records by id. (Which is quite logical, if you know the id then why do you need this feature at all?)

So if the id parameter is provided in the request then use `findById(id)` directly, **otherwise** fill all the provided properties of an example object and use the `findAll(Example.of(example))` method.

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what happened. I removed the ID and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I think, its because of this,

```
if (name.isPresent()) {
        newFile.setSize(name.get()); 
}
```

You are doing `newFile.**setSize**(name.get());` but it should(i believe) be `newFile.set**Name**(name.get());`

Comment: The name parameter is null, so it doesn't matter

Comment: Hi, I've added the entity class, and correct the code, it still doesn't find the record.

Comment: Can you add generated query for '/searchFile?id=1'?