# Spring Data JPA : Efficient Way to Invoke Repository Methods with Optional Parameters

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, java-11

I have the below `Java 11` method which is invoked by the controller where `ID` is the required param and `status`,`version` are optional params. I had to write multiple `repository` methods to fetch the record based on those params. Am wondering is there a better/effiecient way to refactor this method with out the if/else ladder?

```
    @Override
    @Transactional(transactionManager = "customTransactionManager")
    public Optional<String> getInformation(UUID id, Status status, Long version) {
        try {
            Preconditions.checkNotNull(id, ID_MUST_BE_NOT_NULL_MSG);
            if (status != null && version != null) {
                return repository.findByIdAndVersionAndStatus(id, version, status);
            } else if (status != null) {
                return repository.findFirstByIdAndStatus(id, status);
            } else if (version != null) {
                return repository.findFirstByIdAndVersion(id, version);
            } else {
                return repository.findFirstByIdOrderByIdDesc(id);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error(e);
            throw new CustomException(MessageFormat.format(PUBLIC_ERROR_MESSAGE, id));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring Data optional parameter in query method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32728843/spring-data-optional-parameter-in-query-method)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [Specifications](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#specifications) for that:

```java
private Specification<YourEntity> toSpecification(UUID id, Status status, Long version) {
    return (root, query, builder) -> {
        Set<Predicate> predicates = new HashSet<>();
        predicates.add(builder.equal(root.get("id"), id));
        if (status != null) predicates.add(builder.equal(root.get("status"), status));
        if (version != null) predicates.add(builder.equal(root.get("version"), version));
        return builder.and(predicates.toArray(Predicate[]::new));
    };
}
```

If you let your repository extend `JpaSpecificationExecutor` you can use the build specification object like so:

```java
Specification<YourEntity> specification = toSpecification(id, status, version);
Optional<YourEntity> result = repository.findOne(specification);
```

When using [Hibernate Metamodel Generator](https://hibernate.org/orm/tooling/#hibernate-metamodel-generator) you can also write `builder.equal(YourEntity_.id, id)` instead of `builder.equal(root.get("id"), id)`.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the accepted answer, I find Query By Examples much more intuitive and simple.

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-query-by-example would be a good start.

It basically creates a query based on non-null fields from your jpa entity.