# Optional parameter in query method with explicit null support in Spring JPA

Tags: java, spring, jpa

As shown in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50792199/16493687), I want to ignore the fields which are not specified in filter but I also want a way to explicitly specify if a field is null.

Basically something like this:

```java
class User {
    String f1;
    String f2;
    String f2;
}

class UserFilter {
    Optional<String> f1;
    Optional<String> f2;
    Optional<String> f3;
}

class UserService {
    List<User> findBy(UserFilter u){
        userRepository.findAll(Example.of(user));
    }
}
```

If `Optional<String>` is null then it should ignore that field but if its not null and is empty then I should explicitly check for nullability condition in database.

e.g If `f1` and `f3` are not null and not empty and `f2` is null then it should `findby` `f1` and `f3` and ignore `f2`'s value but if `f2`'s value is not null and is empty then  it should return entities who's `f2` is null in database.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to include `null` fields in `ExampleMatcher` because default matcher does not include it.

Second if optional is `null` you need to exclude this field.

Short, you can write a method like this:

```java
public static Example<User> getExampleByUserFilter(UserFilter userFilter) {

    User user = new User();
    ExampleMatcher exampleMatcher = ExampleMatcher.matchingAll()
            .withIgnorePaths("id") // (1)
            .withIncludeNullValues();

    Optional<String> optionalF1 = userFilter.getF1();
    if (optionalF1.isPresent()) {
        if (!optionalF1.get().isBlank()) {
            user.setF1(optionalF1.get());
        }
    } else {
        exampleMatcher = exampleMatcher.withIgnorePaths("f1");
    }

    Optional<String> optionalF2 = userFilter.getF2();
    if (optionalF2.isPresent()) {
        if (!optionalF2.get().isBlank()) {
            user.setF2(optionalF2.get());
        }
    } else {
        exampleMatcher = exampleMatcher.withIgnorePaths("f2");
    }

    // other fields ..

    return Example.of(user, exampleMatcher);
}
```

Let's make an example and look at the sql query output:

```java
...

UserFilter userFilter1 = new UserFilter(
        Optional.of("f1"),
        Optional.empty(),
        Optional.of("f3"));

UserFilter userFilter2 = new UserFilter(
        Optional.of("f1"),
        Optional.of(""),
        Optional.of("f3"));

userRepository
        .findAll(getExampleByUserFilter(userFilter1));
userRepository
        .findAll(getExampleByUserFilter(userFilter2));
...
```

The console output for this example:

```sql
Hibernate: select ... from user user0_ 
    where user0_.f1=? and user0_.f3=?
Hibernate: select ... from user user0_ 
    where user0_.f1=? and user0_.f3=? and (user0_.f2 is null)
```

*(1) The important thing here is that you need to eliminate all the fields that you will not use in the filter with `withIgnorePaths(...)` in the first step.*

**`OR`**

I recommend using [`Specifications and Querydsl`](https://spring.io/blog/2011/04/26/advanced-spring-data-jpa-specifications-and-querydsl/) for such conditional operations.

You can extends from `JpaSpecificationExecutor` too and get the `Predicate` with `QueryByExamplePredicateBuilder` from `Example`.