# How to check if is null and if has a specific value using Optional in java?

Tags: java, if-statement, functional-programming, java-8, option-type

Assume that I have this code in my project:

```
public List<T> getAll(Integer parameter) {
    if(parameter != null && parameter > -1) {
        // do something here
    }
}
```

My question is: how can I do the checking with `Optional` instead of using `if`, or if there is another thing I could use?

Comment: If the parameter is optional, then create two methods: One without parameters and one expecting an int. Neither `if` nor `Optional` are good choices here.

Comment: Cannot agree with that comment. Consider three parameters which are all optional. Surely you are not suggesting to make 2^3=8 overloads of the method, especially if every parameter is an Integer (making several different signatures indistinguishable). Of course sometimes we can gather all params inside some other entity, but we will again need to deal with them being optional.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Optional<Integer>`

```
public List<T> getAll(Integer paramter) {
    return Optional.ofNullable(parameter)
      .filter(p -> p > -1);
}
```

The `Optional<>` is just an implementation of Optional pattern. The useful methods is also `Optional<T>#orElse(T default)` which sets the value to default in case there was a `null`,

If you already got interested but still can't answer your doubts, please ask for clarification in comments. I'll respond asap.

Comment: Or [`OptionalInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/OptionalInt.html)

Comment: I decided to use Optional, as the OP uses reference type.

Comment: The if-condition could be shortened to parameter.filter((i) -> i > -1).isPresent()

Comment: @Nevay not every beginner is familiar with lambdas, so I decided to show the *traditional* way.

Comment: @xenteros The OP couldn't help but use a reference type, because they were allowing it to be null - hence converting to an optional type.

Comment: @khelwood ofc you're right. I'm thinking about extending the answer.

Comment: You should not use `Optional` as a parameter to a method. I found this good answer that explains why: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39005452/4137489

Comment: This answer is really bad. Optional as a param is a code smell and proposed way of using an Optional has nothing to do with how it should be used.

Comment: Don’t use `if (parameter.isPresent()`… Use `parameter.ifPresent(`… (works with `OptionalInt` as well as `Optional`).

Comment: Thanks, @marstran, for the very informative link. So I gather: (a) if the caller typically has an `Integer` that may be null, the original method signature should be preserved, and the implementer may look into pivovarit’s answer. (b) if the caller typically would do either `getAll(4)` or `getAll(null)`, the method should be overloaded with one version taking an `int` argument and one version taking no argument.

Answer (score 20):

Optional's design was inspired by monads known from the world of Functional Programming. In such case, it could look like this:

```
public List<T> getAll(Integer parameter) {

    return Optional.ofNullable(parameter)
      .filter(p -> p > -1)
      .map(p -> *some modification*) //this line is optional
      .orElseGet(() -> *some default value, probably an empty list*)
}
```

In such case, condition checking is performed in the `filter` method. If a given `Predicate` is not matched, the underlying `Optional` will be empty.

If you want to perform an operation on the underlying value, use `map` method by providing it with a `Function` that should be applied to the element wrapped by the `Optional`.

At the end, you can simply perform some action using `ifPresent()`, thrown an exception `orElseThrow` or simply return a default value with `orElse` or `orElseGet`. Keep in mind that `orElseGet` accepts a `Supplier` instance which makes it evaluate the default value lazily.

If you want to dig deeper, check out @stuart-marks talk from Devoxx: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ej0sss6cq14&t=2767s

In your case, there might be no need for an Optional at all. Just two methods. One with the parameter and the other without.

Comment: I'm sorry for being accepted answer. Upvoting your answer and wishing you a populist badge here.

Comment: _"it should look like this"_ I don't think so. In a comment to another answer you wrote _"Optional as a param is a code smell", but your code essentially does just that. Whether you expect an `Optional` or create one makes no difference. The code smell is the optional parameter, not the usage of `Optional`.

Comment: @zeroflagL well, creating an Optional instance only to benefit from the API is questionable but keep in mind that it's encapsulated and not exposed to the world. You do not force users to wrap everything into an Optional.

Answer (score 9):

### You should not use `Optional` for such a case

As [Stuart Marks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1441122/stuart-marks) states in [Optional - The Mother of All Bikesheds](https://youtu.be/Ej0sss6cq14):

> **[Rule #4](https://youtu.be/Ej0sss6cq14?t=27m51s)**: It's generally a bad idea to create an Optional for the specific purpose of chaining methods from it to get a value.

This creates a useless overhead without any improvement for code readability and maintainability. You should thus not wrap your parameter into an optional.

and

> **[Rule #6](https://youtu.be/Ej0sss6cq14?t=40m40s)**: Avoid using Optional in fields, method parameters and collections.
>
> **Avoid using Optional in method parameters**
>
> - it doesn't really work for making parameters optional
> - forces call sites to create Optionals for everything:
>
>   `myMethod(Optional.of("some value"));`
>
>   `myMethod(Optional.empty());`

See also [Why should Java 8's Optional not be used in arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31922866/why-should-java-8s-optional-not-be-used-in-arguments).

Answer (score -1):

You need to be clear about what you expect of your method. Possibilities:

- You want it to keep working as before, and handle the case where the client supplies a null
- You want to change the method to accept `Optional<Integer>` as its parameter. The "no nulls" way, is to do this, and simply not accommodate callers who supply null -- if they get a NullPointerException, it's their own fault because they broke the rules.

You don't have to work with streams or lambdas to work with Optional (although of course, you can).

You could simply write:

```
public List<T> getAll(Optional<Integer> maybeParameter) {
    if(maybeParameter.isPresent() && maybeParameter.get() > -1) {
        // do something here
    }
}
```

Look at `Optional`'s other methods in JavaDoc, to see how else it can be used.

If you didn't want to change the signature of your method, you could use `Optional.ofNullable()` to turn an `Integer` into an `Optional<Integer>`:

```
public List<T> getAll(Integer parameter) {
    Optional<Integer> maybeParameter = Optional.ofNullable(parameter);
    // work with the Optional here as before...
}
```

However I question the value of doing this here. If your API accepts nulls, then handling it with `Optional` "behind the scenes" doesn't provide an advantage.

I feel the best use of `Optional` is to expose it as part of your API. If a parameter is optional, declare it as `Optional` rather than handling null (or better, use method overloading, so they don't have to pass anything at all). If a return value might not be set, make the return type `Optional`, rather than ever returning null.

Answer (score -2):

```
import java.util.Optional;

public class ExampleNullCheck{

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Integer a = null;
        Optional<Integer> checkInt = Optional.ofNullable(a);
        System.out.println(checkInt.isPresent());
    }//main

}//class
```

Comment: This answers only half of the question.