# The method copyOf(Map<? extends K,? extends V>) in the type ImmutableMap is not applicable for the arguments (Optional<Map<String,String>>)

Tags: java, java-8

I have a function definition which takes  Optional> as a parameter.

To call the function I create:

```
    Optional<Map<String, String>> options = Optional.ofNullable(config.getMap(
                    OPTIONS, String.class, String.class)); 
myfunc(ImmutableMap.copyOf(options));
```

However I get an error: `The method copyOf(Map<? extends K,? extends V>) in the type ImmutableMap is not applicable for the arguments (Optional<Map<String,String>>)`

Is there a way to allow copyOf to use Optional map ?

Comment: You have to copy the wrapped object, not the Optional itself. For example, `Optional<Map<String, String>> copy = options.isPresent() ? Optional.of(ImmutableMap.copyOf(options.get())) : Optional.empty();`.

Comment: @teppic Thanks. It is Optional<ImmutableMap<String, String>> copy

Comment: You should not use an optional map at all. The canonical representation of an absent map is an empty map, which works for most use cases.

Comment: [`Optional` should not be used as a method arguments.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31922866/why-should-java-8s-optional-not-be-used-in-arguments)

Comment: Also, even @teppic's solution is a contrived way of reimplementing `Optional.map()`. Using `Optional.isPresent()` followed by `Optional.get()` is a bad smell and most often bad usage of the API. They might deprecate `Optional.get()` to discourage this.