# Concatenate Multiple variables to a String in Java If Else Block

Tags: java, if-statement, null, concatenation, string-concatenation

I need to create a string which becomes an input to a SHA 256 function to generate its hash equivalent. The string is created by concatenating several variables as below:

```
String strRequest = "";

strRequest = request_passphrase.concat("access_code=").concat(access_code).concat("amount=").concat(amount).concat("command=").concat(mode).concat("currency=").concat(currency).concat("merchant_identifier=").concat(merchant_identifier).concat(request_passphrase);
if(strRequest!="" || !strRequest.isEmpty()) {
  signature = sha256(strRequest);
}
```

What should be the best way to create an if-else to drop concatenation for a variable which is null.

For ex. if access_code is Null or empty, then the string will be request_passphrase.concat("amount=").concat(amount). and so on.

Comment: have you heard of `Map`? would be useful here. P.S. you seem to be building a Querystring. Searching for that term will find lots.

Comment: Note: `strRequest!="" || !strRequest.isEmpty()` is always true, given the previous line. And `strRequest != ""` almost certainly isn't checking what you think it does.

Comment: Thanks Andy. Have corrected it now. Have used the && instead of OR now and used strRequest ! = null.

Comment: Thanks for the quick upvote!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on your context, the reasonable answer *could* be to organize your data differently:

```
request_passphrase.concat("access_code=").concat(access_code)
```

Instead of having a flat list of fields (or worse: method parameters), you could pass some sort of `Map<String, String>` - where the key denotes the "field name", like ("access_code"); and the map value represents, well, the corresponding value. And if that value is null, you know to not append it.

Then you can simply iterate that map object, pull key/value pairs and append them to that string. Maybe you need an additional list that tells you the **order** in which the map keys should be iterated.

As said: these are *options*. In order to make a clear decision, one should understand more of the context; the underlying "data model"; other requirements, etc. The one thing that is definitely sure: if/else chains are **never** a good idea.

Comment: I believe that your solution is very good (upvoted). I do understand the problem and do not know how to get into Optional variable's _name_. Depending on what the OP wants to do a `Map<String, String>` or a `Map<String, Optional<String>>` may be best fits for him/her.

Comment: On the other hand, the java fathers say: optionals should only be used as return type of methods ( see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31922866/why-should-java-8s-optional-not-be-used-in-arguments for example ).

Answer (score 3):

Wrap strings in Java 8 `Optional`:

```
Optional<String> accessCode = Optional.ofNullable("access");
Optional<String> addressCode = Optional.ofNullable(null);

System.out.println(accessCode.orElse("It was null."));
System.out.println(addressCode.orElse("It was null."));
```

In your particular case `"It was null."` should be replaced with an empty string.

Besides. Use an instance of `StringBuilder` to minimize`String` constructor calls.
Typical usage:

```
StringBuilder outputBuilder = new StringBuilder("");
while (condition) {
    outputBuilder.append(" another chunk ");
}
outputBuilder.append("end.");
String outputString = outputBuilder.toString();
```

And besides, you can filter out "nullable" parameters with a `Map<String, Optional<String>>`.
This would be a very good idea.

Comment: Depending on the number of strings, concat() might be better than StringBuilder ... see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/47605/string-concatenation-concat-vs-operator

Comment: @GhostCat really that was the worst thing you could say about this answer? if there are only two strings then it's going to be fast either way.

Comment: @PatrickParker What makes you think so; you are not a moderator; so you can't see the comments that went forth and back between me and Greg already ;-) ... and hint: if I do complain about the quality of an answer, then people notice. Here, I even upvoted. I just wanted to point out that things are not that simple performance wise ;-)

Comment: @GhostCat what I mean to say is, I can see a lot of bad things with this answer. But that is not one of them.

Comment: You can always step in, edit, or add a specific comment. I have made the experience more than once that *constructive* critique is well appreciated. Esp. as most people understand that fixing problems might lead to upvotes.