# java.util.Objects vs Optional which is preferable?

Tags: java, option-type, java-9

The [java.util.Objects](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html) class was extended with a number of new methods

[Objects#requireNonNullElse](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#requireNonNullElse-T-T-.)

respectively

[Objects#requireNonNullElseGet()](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#requireNonNullElseGet-T-java.util.function.Supplier-.) in `Java-9`.

Both will return the first argument if it is non-null and otherwise returns the non-null second argument or the non-null value of supplier.get()

```
jshell> String nullStr = null;
nullStr ==> null

jshell> Objects.requireNonNullElse(nullStr,"lorem ipsum");
$13 ==> "lorem ipsum"

jshell> Objects.requireNonNullElseGet(nullStr,() -> "lorem ipsum");
$14 ==> "lorem ipsum"
```

But the new functionality overlaps with already existing in the `Optional` class [Optional#orElse](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#orElse-T-) and [Optional#orElseGet](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#orElseGet-java.util.function.Supplier-.)

```
jshell> Optional.ofNullable(nullStr).orElse("lorem ipsum");
$17 ==> "lorem ipsum"

jshell> Optional.ofNullable(nullStr).orElseGet(() -> "lorem ipsum");
$18 ==> "lorem ipsum"
```

The only difference between new methods in `Objects` and corresponding `Optional` methods is that second argument or value of supplier must be non-null otherwise `Objects` throws `NPE`:

```
jshell> Objects.requireNonNullElseGet(nullStr,() -> null);
|  java.lang.NullPointerException thrown: supplier.get()
|        at Objects.requireNonNull (Objects.java:246)
|        at Objects.requireNonNullElseGet (Objects.java:321)
|        at (#15:1)

jshell> Objects.requireNonNullElse(nullStr,null);
|  java.lang.NullPointerException thrown: defaultObj
|        at Objects.requireNonNull (Objects.java:246)
|        at Objects.requireNonNullElse (Objects.java:301)
|        at (#16:1)
```

versus `Optional`

```
jshell> Optional.ofNullable(nullStr).orElse(null);
$19 ==> null

jshell> Optional.ofNullable(nullStr).orElseGet(() -> null);
$20 ==> null
```

- Why haven't the JDK developers updated existing methods in Optional
  class?
- Why haven't they introduced a new method (which will thrown
  NPE if second argument is null) to Optional class?
- What should we use now Optional or Objects?
- Do new methods make Objects more preferable than Optional since they
  will throw NPE immediately and not later on somewhere in the code
  like with Optional?

If I have a legacy code, something like:

```
String str = null; 
String result = str == null ? "other string" : str;
```

Which is just a simple check inside a method. And I would like to re-factor it using latest language features. Now having in mind the difference between `Optional.orElse`  and `Objects.requireNonNullOrElse` which is preferable?

```
result = Optional.ofNullable(str).orElse("other string");
```

or

```
result = Objects.requireNonNullOrElse(str,"other string);
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The shortest answer to your question "which is preferable?" is the all-time developer favorite "it depends"  because `Objects::requireNonNullElse` and `Optional` cover different use cases.

### The Two Alternatives

Before answering your questions I want to give some background on the two alternatives.

#### `Objects::requireNonNullElse`

`Objects::requireNonNull` makes sure that the result of the call is never null (hence the name). It is usually used to succinctly verify constructor or method arguments and allows readers to verify with a glance that the variable to which the return value is assigned can not be null.

So it would not only be weird for `Objects::requireNonNullElse` to suddenly allow `null`, it would also be borderline useless because:

```
// if requireNonNullGet would allow null as second argument,
// the following is true for all x (including null)
Objects.requireNonNullElse(x, null) == x
```

You might argue that it is different for `requireNonNullElseGet` because that might call a function that, depending on some state, might return `null` or not. That's true and I assume it was considered but the `requireNonNull...` API would be really weird if one of the three cases might actually allow the final result of the call to be `null` even though the name says *required non null*.

#### `Optional`

`Optional` [was designed](http://blog.codefx.org/java/dev/design-optional/) as a return argument in cases where returning `null` is very likely to cause NPEs (like for a `Stream`'s terminal operation, where it was first used). Although some developers prefer to use it in more cases (compare [Stephen Colebourne's pragmatic approach](http://blog.joda.org/2015/08/java-se-8-optional-pragmatic-approach.html) and [my strict approach](http://blog.codefx.org/java/stephen-colebourne-optional-a-strict-approach/)) no one really proposes using it as in your demonstration:

```
Optional.ofNullable(nullStr).orElse(null);
Optional.ofNullable(nullStr).orElseGet(() -> null);
```

`Optional` is a way to express in the type system that something might be missing - it is not meant as an alternative to `if`-`null`-checks. In that sense `orElse` or `orElseGet` are backdoors out of `Optional` back into the world of nullable types and sometimes `null` is just what you want to use if something's not there, so it makes sense for them to accept `null` as an argument (or the supplier's result).

### Your Questions

Now we have what we need to answer your questions:

> Why haven't the JDK developers updated existing methods in Optional class?

Conceptually that would go against what `Optional` should be used for. But, as others have mentioned, this would be a backwards incompatible change as calls to `orElse(null)` would suddenly throw exceptions.

> Why haven't they introduced a new method (which will thrown NPE if second argument is null) to Optional class?

APIs are only extended if considerable improvements of existing code can be expected. I don't see that here. In many cases `orElse` gets an argument that the caller creates specifically as an alternative for empty optionals - there is rarely a need to make an extra check to verify it's not `null`. If you really have to, call `orElse(requireNonNull(x))`.

> What should we use now Optional or Objects?

If you have a variable (be it local, an argument or a field) and you want to make sure it's not null, use `Objects`. If you want to return something, which may be null consider wrapping it in `Optional`. Be suspicious of code that creates an `Optional` (as opposed to getting one form a call) and unwraps it at the end of the same chain.

> Do new methods make Objects more preferable than Optional since they will throw NPE immediately and not later on somewhere in the code like with Optional?

As I'm sure is clear by now, they cover different use cases. But let me address "and not later on somewhere in the code like with Optional": Whatever you do, make sure to check your desired nullablity property (can be `null` or not) in your code. Don't return something that you assume can not be `null` but it turns out to be because you didn't check. If that happens, it's not `Optional`'s fault.

> If I have a legacy code, something like:
>
> ```
> String str = null; 
> String result = str == null ? "other string" : str;
> ```

Definitely `Objects.requireNonNullOrElse(str,"other string");` and consider using static imports to make it more readable.

Comment: I guess I was using `Optional` in a wrong way. I was thinking that I can use them as an alternative for `if-null-check`. Now I will review my approach. Thanks a lot.

Comment: That's what SO is there for. :) Remember to accept one of the answers if you're question were fully addressed.

Answer (score 4):

> Why haven't the JDK developers updated existing methods in Optional class?

Because that would introduce a breaking change that would break many existing programs, and because the method should allow getting null if desired.

> Why haven't they introduced a new method (which will thrown NPE if second argument is null) to Optional class?

Probably because that would make the API more convoluted and bloated for no significant advantage. You can still wrap the result with requireNonNull if you want to ensure your code doesn't return null unexpectedly.

> What should we use now Optional or Objects?

If you need to extract a value out of an optional returned by a method, then use Optional's method. If you want to ensure preconditions are respected for the argument of a method that should not be null, use Object.requireXxx. The JDK designers have never advocated the use of Optional just to wrap a value and check for null. Optional is for return values.

> Do new methods make Objects more preferable than Optional since they will throw NPE immediately and not later on somewhere in the code like with Optional?

See previous points: you don't use these methods to do the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

The point is: those two method signatures are **clearly** different:

```
public static <T> T requireNonNullElse(T obj, T defaultObj)
```

vs.

```
public static <T> T requireNonNullElseGet(T obj, Supplier<? extends T> supplier)
```

The [javadoc](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#requireNonNullElseGet-T-java.util.function.Supplier-) for the second method reads:

*Returns the first argument if it is non-null and otherwise returns the non-null value of supplier.get().*

In other words: it uses the **supplier** that you provide to it here.

So, the answer is: you use the second version for situations where you **want** to work with a supplier; and otherwise you simply take the "more simple" version of that method that takes the "less complicated" parameter.

The reasoning behind that: when you decide between two options, you prefer that one that is easier/"less reader surprising" to use. In other words: why would you want to provide a supplier, when you can go without.

Regarding the **usage of Optionals** - keep in mind that their **main** goal was to be used for return types; not as method parameters (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31922866/why-should-java-8s-optional-not-be-used-in-arguments) for further reading).

Then: **updating** existing methods in a class delivered "to the field" is almost always a no-go. You absolutely do **not** want to change the semantics of something that is already out in the open and used by your customers; assuming specific semantics.

Comment: Yes, but both `Optinal#orElseGet` and `Objects.requireNotNullElseGet` accept supplier.  And the only difference that second one will throw NPE if `supplier.get()`  returns null.

Comment: That aspect is covered in the last paragraph - the people who give us Java think that using Optional as method parameter isn't a good practice; so why would they put up an official method signature that does exactly that?!

Comment: I was thinking more about following situation.  Let's say there is a check inside a method: `String str = null; String result = str == null ? "other string" : str;` It is not a method parameter. Just a check. Now I would like to refactor it using latest language features.  Having in mind the difference between `Objects` and `Optional`. Which is more preferable  `result = Optional.ofNullable(str).orElse("other string");`  or  `result = Objects.requireNonNullOrElse(str,"other string);` ?

Answer (score 1):

> Q. Why haven't the JDK developers updated existing methods in Optional class?

A. Because `Optional` class was designed to avoid NPE.

> Q. Why haven't they introduced a new method (which will thrown NPE if second argument is null) to Optional class?

A. The same answer.

> Q. What should we use now Optional or Objects?.

A. Both. `Objects` for simple "not null" checkings and `Optional` for chain operations like `map`, `flatMap`, `filter'.

> Q. Do new methods make Objects more preferable than Optional since they will throw NPE immediately and not later on somewhere in the code like with Optional?

A. Depends on situation. If you already have Optional as return value of some method then it is preferable to use Optional.

Answer (score 0):

So the main point is if you like using ifs for checking for null or not. If you have a method that can take arguments that can be of null value, It would make more sense to use Objects. The only reasonable place to use Optional is to verify a call to a method that returns optional result.

Developers wanted to use more functional way of checking for null values, so the where using the construct `Optional.ofNullable` for that purpose, which wasn't a good practice, because it was creating garbage.