# More succinct code for a defensive copy using Guava's immutable types?

Tags: java, coding-style, guava, defensive-copy

I want to make a defensive copy of a collection passed into a method using Guava's immutable types, e.g. an `ImmutableList`. I must also be able to deal with `null` input and treat that like an empty collection.

The cleanest I could come up with was this:

```
  public void setStrings(List<String> strings) {
     this.strings = strings == null ? ImmutableList.of() : ImmutableList.copyOf(strings);
  }
```

Is there something more readable, preferably without the ternary operator? I wouldn't consider `Optional.of(strings).map(...).orElse(...)` as a nice alternative due to the reasoning that I share with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42482326/java-util-objects-vs-optional-which-is-preferable/42484416#42484416).

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your current code, aside the fact you might pass in `null` in the first place.

Comment: This is code in a DTO used for deserializing JSON by Jackson. The interface is kind of foggy, so it should be possible to pass in either an empty array or `null` and applying the same semantics. Therefore, it's out of my control, unfortunately.

Comment: Then I don't see anything wrong with your current code :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`MoreObjects.firstNonNull`](https://guava.dev/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/base/MoreObjects.html#firstNonNull(T,%20T)), which is also from Guava:

```
public void setStrings(List<String> strings) {
     this.strings = ImmutableList.copyOf(MoreObjects.firstNonNull(strings, Collections.emptyList()));
}
```

Alternatively [`ListUtils.emptyIfNull`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/ListUtils.html#emptyIfNull-java.util.List-) is a similar but more specialized method in Apache Commons Collections which is more clear and easier to read in my opinion:

```
public void setStrings(List<String> strings) {
     this.strings = ImmutableList.copyOf(ListUtils.emptyIfNull(strings));
}
```

Comment: You could stick to using `ImmutableList.of()` rather than `Collections.emptyList()` - `copyOf` avoids creating a copy if it's already an `ImmutableList`.