# How to reduce on groups and return a sorted list with the Java 8 Stream API

Tags: java

Is there a simpler way to do the following groupBy with reduction and sort? I can't figure out how to avoid having to unwrap the Optional or why the Optional is even there to begin with.

The given `List<Response>` contains many responses. For each group of `Response` entities (grouped by `taskId`), I would like ONLY the `Response` for that group with the latest `submissionDateTime`. The `submissionDateTime` is an `Optional<OffsetDateTime>` on the `Response` entity.

```
Comparator<Response> bySubmissionDate = Comparator.comparing(
    r -> r.getSubmissionDateTime().orElse(OffsetDateTime.MAX)
);
List<Response> responses = responses.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
            Response::getTaskId,
            Collectors.reducing(maxBy(bySubmissionDate))
        )).values().stream()
        .map(Optional::get)
        .sorted(bySubmissionDate)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Surely there must be a better way to do this. The final ordering is important, hence the final `.sorted(bySubmissionDate)` criteria.

**EDIT**
Given the responses, I've been able to reduce the code as follows:

```
List<Response> responses = responses.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                ResponseComplete::getTaskId,
                Collectors.maxBy(bySubmissionDate)
            )).values().stream()
            .map(Optional::get)
            .sorted(bySubmissionDate)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Also of note, `submissionDateTime` is an `Optional<OffsetDateTime>` on the `Response` interface. The actual `submissionDateTime` is not a field-level `Optional`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ... or why the Optional is even there to begin with.

This is a safety measure for when reducing an empty stream. What is the maximum in that case? It's unknown, so there might or might not be an actual return value. That's where the optional comes in.

But in this case you can always call `Optional.get` safely since a group resulting from `groupingBy` will never be empty. If there are no elements in a group a list would simply never be created for it. (however, the reducing collector does not know that.)

Your approach is fine.

---

P.S., you could also use the `maxBy` collector directly.

Answer (score 0):

This makes it a tiny little bit simpler. I think it is not necessary to wrap `maxBy` in a `reduce`.

Regarding your question about the necessity of `Optional#get`: A presume the cause for that is, that after a reduction, the outcome could be 'empty'. Thus the Optional. 
In your case, if the Optional indeed is empty, calling `Optinal#get` would cause an Exception. Since you do a `maxBy` operation and your Comparator handles null I guess you are save. Otherwise you should filter first.

```
responses.stream()
    .collect(
        Collectors.groupingBy(Response::getTaskId, 
        Collectors.maxBy(bySubmissionDate))).values().stream()
    .map(Optional::get)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Another note: It seems your submissionDateTime is of Type Optional. It is not recommended using Optionals as field types. See [Why should Java 8's Optional not be used in arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31922866/why-should-java-8s-optional-not-be-used-in-arguments)

Comment: The field itself is an `OffsetDateTime`. The `Optional<OffsetDateTime>` comes from the interface. Sorry, I don't think I made that clear in my question.

Comment: @varcharmander No need to be sorry :). In that case maybe use getOptionalSubmissionDateTime because of getter convention. Just a side note.