# Do Java optional parameters make @NonNull annotations redundant?

Tags: java

I’m working on a new codebase and I’m wondering, since all non-optional parameters in my code throw an IllegalArgumentException when passed null, does it even make sense to use annotations like @NonNull? Or is it better to expect programmers know I always use Optional to indicate not passing in any value is a valid action here? (Of course assuming I also say that in javadoc, etc.)

Comment: @NonNull can be used by your IDE, your exception not.

Comment: [Many think that Optional should not be used for parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31922866/3788176).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a `null` to a parameter that expects an `Optional` so you could argue that `@NonNull` is still useful.

Personally I think `@NonNull` becomes redudant because if you call a method that expects an `Optional` you would pass `Optional.empty()` and never `null` when the value is absent. Keep in mind that java conventions discorages the use of `Optional` in parameters.

I disagree with this convention as `Optional` already conveys the meaning that the underlying method is prepared to deal with the absence of a value.

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately this is a matter of opinion and preference, but I don't think `@NonNull` is necessary if it's well established that your code is null-hostile. Guava takes such an approach and uses a `@Nullable` annotation to indicate the occasional exception.