# Initialize fileds in DTO

Tags: java, dto

A friend of me advices me to initialise DTO fields of type (ArrayList)
and only of type ArrayList in DTOs like this to avoid NullPointerException

```
public class fooDto {
    private SomeClasse someClasse = new SomeClasse();
    private ArrayList<Bar> bars = new ArrayList();
}
```

should we do his ? and is it a good practice

in other way , should we use "= new SomeClasse()" or not ?

Comment: No, because you're assigning a raw type to the generic list.

Comment: Or are you asking if fields should be initialized with an empty value or left uninitialized (null)?

Comment: Make the field `final`and you won't have these problems.

Comment: Not sure about good practice but we do it all the time for List objects to avoid NPE like your friend suggested.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With **List**, definitelly yes (it is unfotunatelly quite common to try to put an item to a null list). However about **someClasse**, well it depends. If you're trying to avoid at all cost annoying null check than perhaps it is ok. However if **someClasse** is an optional field than why should it be initialised? On the other hand if it should not be null than perhaps it is for the best to let this exception be thrown . After all it is easy to find a cause of it, otherwise you would be stack with analisis was it actually set by something to empty value or was it empty because of some mistake? 
To sumarise in my opinion you gain more by not initialising it. You always could use some [preconditions](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/PreconditionsExplained) to easy check null value and throw more civilized exception.

Answer (score 1):

I think for a `Collection` it would make sense to initialize it. When it comes to other properties like your `SomeClass` example this might differ per case.

You **could** use the Null Object design pattern, which is a pattern that should avoid having a real `null` value by accident.

Comment: It is not a good practice to use Optional as fields. Example source here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31922866/why-should-java-8s-optional-not-be-used-in-arguments

Comment: @pokemzok makes sense for data structures, would make more sense in services/repositories. removed it from my comment.

Answer (score 0):

Depends how you are using these DTO's.

It make sense to do when you have to manually copy data from domain object to DTO.

Otherwise, if you're using a library for that, like `ModelMapper`, `beanutils` or something similar it looks a bit redundant to me, since such tools can handle nulls and all this kind of stuff.