# Optional as parameter not working properly

Tags: java, option-type

I may be having it wrong but i am getting an error with an `Optional<>` as method argument in Java.

I have an interface:

```
public interface FooInterface;
```

And a class that implements it

```
public class Foo implements FooInterface;
```

Now, suppose i have a method that receives an `Optional<FooInterface>`

```
someMethod(Optional<FooInterface> arg)
```

I get an error if i do this:

```
Optional<Foo> foo = Optional.of(new Foo());
someMethod(foo);
```

It says that `Optional<FooInterface>` is expected instead of `Optional<Foo>`.

Why is that?

Comment: Try `someMethod(Optional<? extends FooInterface> arg)`.

Comment: See also [Why should Java 8's Optional not be used in arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31922866/why-should-java-8s-optional-not-be-used-in-arguments)

Comment: If possible modify `someMethod` method signature suggested by Henrik else try `Optional<FooInterface> foo = Optional.of((FooInterface) new Foo());`

Answer (score 1):

1. Use the interface type `FooInterface`:

   ```
   final FooInterface foo = new Foo();
   final Optional<FooInterface> optional = Optional.of(foo);
   ```
2. Correct the argument type to `Optional<? extends FooInterface>`. It'll allow passing an `Optional<AnyFooInterfaceSubclass>`.
3. [Try not using the `Optional` for parameters and fields.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31922866/why-should-java-8s-optional-not-be-used-in-arguments)

Answer (score 1):

That is a general drawback of generic types involving `extends/implements`.

```
interface Ifc { }
class Cls implements Ifc { }
void somemethod2(List<Ifc> arg) { }

List<Cls> list = new UnlinkedList<>();
somemethod2(list); // COMPILE ERROR
```

In your case a solution would be:

```
somemethod(Optional<FooInterface>.of(foo));
```

Or declare

```
void someMethod(Optional<? extends FooInterface> arg) {
```

Fortunately Optional is immutable, but for List this would be problematically, as you could not set an element with Foo, as it could have been a List of an other FooInterface implementing class. So maybe better to avoid.

---

There exist some proponents of avoiding Optional parameters, in favor of doing only work on non-optional objects. I do not see that as such. IMHO there are many valid uses of Optional parameters.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with `Optional` itself, it applies to any generic type.

Java generics are invariant, which means `Collection<Foo>` (or `Optional`, or whatever) is not a subtype of `Collection<FooInterface>`, even though `Foo` itself is a subtype of `FooInterface`.

You need to make that generic type covariant using a wildcard (as @Henrik pointed out already):

```
/**
 * accepts an optional value of type `FooInterface` or any subtype
 */
someMethod(Optional<? extends FooInterface> arg);
```