# Conditional extract of value from Java Optional

Tags: java, option-type

I am trying to find the most concise (and meaningful) way of using Java `Optional`, to read the first value off a `Optional<String>` and return the String if exists, or return "NOT_FOUND". Here is the code I am working with:

```
public static String getValue(Optional<String> input) {
    return input.ifPresent(val -> val.get()).orElse("NOT_FOUND")
}
```

The methods of Optional apparently have very specific purposes but the API has left me confused.

**Update (4/13/2018):**
The code in my question is incorrect, because if I regarded `val` as the value inside the Optional, then `val.get()` does not make any sense. Thanks for pointing that out, @rgettman.

Also, I added another part to my question in the accepted answer's comments, i.e. I needed a way to manipulate the String value, if present, before returning. The `orElse("NOT_FOUND")` is still applicable, if the Optional does not contain a value. So what is an acceptable use of the `Optional` API to achieve the following?

```
public static String getValue(Optional<String> input) {
    return input.isPresent() ? input.get().substring(0,7).toUpperCase() : "NOT_FOUND";
}
```

@Aominè's answer and follow up comments addressed both parts of this question.

Comment: What is `val`?  Are you attempting to use the return value of `val.get()` somehow?

Comment: Actually, `val` is the value in the Optional, so`val.get()` wouldn't even compile. I am trying to get the value in the Optional and return it from the method if a value is present.

Comment: @WebUser `input` is an `Optional<String>`, `val` is a `String`. see this  [Guide To Java 8 Optional](http://www.baeldung.com/java-optional) then see the java doc on the type [ifPresent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#ifPresent-java.util.function.Consumer-) returns.

Comment: @Aominè point taken, and appreciate the extra links you provided.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All you have to do is change your return statement to:

```
return input.orElse("NOT_FOUND");
```

This will return the object in the Optional if present else returns "NOT_FOUND".

That said, I'd avoid using Optional's as parameters. see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31922866/why-should-java-8s-optional-not-be-used-in-arguments).

Comment: It's amazing how readable that is! But what if I wanted to manipulate the value in `input` before returning it? The equivalent of `return input.isPresent() ? input.get().substring(0,7).toUpperCase() : "NOT_FOUND";` I tried `return input.map(val -> val.substring(0,7).toUpperCase()).orElse("NOT_FOUND");` and it appears to work. Is that an appropriate use of the API to achieve the results I am after, or can I do better?

Comment: @WebUser The latter is better as it's more readable (IMO) and yes that is the appropriate use of the API to achieve the results you're after.

Comment: Thanks for confirming!

Answer (score 1):

If you need to manipulate the string value, if it is present before returning it, use `map` [method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#map-java.util.function.Function-):

```
public static String getValue(Optional<String> input) {
    return input.map(s -> s.substring(0,7).toUpperCase()).orElse("NOT_FOUND");
}
```

If `input` is empty the method returns default value - `"NOT_FOUND"`, otherwise capitalized part of the string is returned.

```
getValue(Optional.ofNullable(null));
$6 ==> "NOT_FOUND"

getValue(Optional.of("some long string"));
$7 ==> "SOME LO"
```