# Java Method Best Practices

Tags: java, methods

Consider a method with objects as parameters. Is it a good practice to check object as not null within method or should I check it before calling that method. I am feeling that if someone is using the method later, if they pass null for a parameter, the method will fail to convey what it is missing. Please suggest the best one from the below methods.

Method 1:

```
void method(Object obj1, Object obj2)
{
  if(obj1!=null && obj2!=null
  {}
}
```

Method 2:

```
void method(Object obj1, Object obj2)
{
  //logic
}
```

Method 3:

```
void method(Object obj1, Object obj2)
{
  if(obj1 ! =null && obj2 !=null)
  {//logic}

  throw exception();
}
```

Comment: In public APIs I always do something like `Objects.requireNotNull(obj1, "obj1 must not be null")`.

Comment: Have a rule, and stay consistent. Mine is to check all input parameters inside public functions, and never within private methods. So when I find myself performing null validation outside the same function call over and over again, it's time to redesign.

Comment: @lexicore an important point about your suggestion is that you will know exactly what is wrong: if you throw an exception because obj1 is null or ob2 is null, you don't know which, and that makes debugging harder.

Comment: @AndyTurner I got called paranoid for this more than once.

Comment: You solve this by documenting what the requirement is for each parameter and what will happen if that requirement isn’t met

Comment: use `Optional<?>` for arguments that can be null and either check for null on arguments that are not permitted to be null (and throw an exception if they are null; perhaps IllegalArgumentException) or don't check for null and accept that it will sometimes throw NullPointerException.  In either case (on the ilegally null side) write a junit case that tests the expected outcome of passing a null.

Comment: @DwB Optional is not meant to be used as a method parameter. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31922866/

Comment: @killjoy `Optional` is designed to represent "maybe something is there".  While it is not a good practice to use it as a method parameter, the "intent" of `Optional` is unclear from the JavaDoc.

Answer (score 1):

There is a few things you could do in this situation. The first thing I suggest doing is using [jsr305 findbugs](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.findbugs/jsr305) or similar (`@Nullable` and`@Nonnull`) to explicitly mark a parameter or method as accepting or returning null. If you have your IDE configured properly, it will know about these and try to prevent null pointers.

```
public void foo(@Nonnull Bar bar) {
```

Another thing you can do is throw an `IllegalArgumentException` if the parameter is null when you asked for nonnull. This will crash the application and the blame will be on the developer.

```
    if (bar == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException("bar cannot be null");
```

There are a few libraries that have methods for this. e.g. Guava's `Preconditions` and Commons-Lang's `Validate`. They also have method for other validations, such as range and states.

Java 8 also has a method `Objects.requireNonNull()`

```
    Objects.requireNonNull(bar);
    Preconditions.checkNotNull(bar);
    Validate.notNull(bar);
```

Answer (score -2):

Checking argument for being null prior to passing it to a method is something that must be addressed on the client side.

Regarding best practices for method writing: I believe it is a good practice to take no assumptions on validity of passed parameters. You should throw IllegalArgumentException if your method cannot operate with null arguments passed.

Comment: Don't rely upon calling code to enforce your preconditions. If it matters to your code, check it in your code.