# Unmarshal missing xml attribute to an optional java object

Tags: java, jaxb, option-type, unmarshalling

I'm trying to unmarshal xml file which have some optional attributes (the attribute can be included in an element, but sometimes it's missing).
How can I create an optional java objects from those attributes?

XML:

```
...
<example a="s"
     b="2.0"
/>
<example a="z"
/>
...
```

Java:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "example")
public class ExampleDTO {

  private String a;
  private Optional<Float> b;

  public String getA() {
    return a;
  }

  @XmlAttribute
  public void setA(String a) {
    this.a = a;
  }

  public Optional<Float> getB() {
    return b;
  }

  @XmlAttribute
  @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(FloatOptionalAdapter.class)
  public void setB(Optional<Float> b) {
    this.b= b;
  }
```

Adapter:

```
public class FloatOptionalAdapter extends XmlAdapter<Float, Optional<Float>> {

  @Override
  public Optional<Float> unmarshal(Float v) throws Exception {
    return Optional.ofNullable(v);
  }

  @Override
  public Float marshal(Optional<Float> v) throws Exception {
    if (v == null || !v.isPresent()) {
      return null;
    } else {
      return v.get();
    }
  }
}
```

When I run this code I get 2 objects of ExampleDTO. In the first one, I get Optional object with "2.0" value. In the second one, the value of b is "null".
How can I make the value to be an empty Optional object?

Comment: if `setB` is not always guaranteed to be invoked and you want the default value of `b` to be `Optional.empty()` instead of nullity then do `private Optional<Float> b = Optional.empty();`. Btw, you should never leave an `Optional<T>` field in a null state as it basically defeats the purpose of it.

Comment: @Aominè Why not post it as an answer?

Comment: @lexicore  sure, thing ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, don't ever leave `Optional<T>` fields in a *null* state as it simply defeats the whole purpose of using the `Optional<T>` type.

Ensure, they have a 
 *non-null* value before allowing users of the API to access it and perform operations upon it, e.g. `private Optional<Float> b;` would be much better being declared as `private Optional<Float> b = Optional.empty()` (which actually might solve your current issue).

Further, I am not a fan of using Optional's as method parameters ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31922866/why-should-java-8s-optional-not-be-used-in-arguments)).

The fact that your `setB` consumes an `Optional<T>` means that anyone can assign any value to the `b` field, and that means one can even do `setB(null)`, oops...

As mentioned ideally you should avoid using optional's as parameters but if you want to keep it as is then I'd suggest performing some validation to prevent `null` being passed to the `setB(...)` method as again it defeats the purpose of using Optional.

Finally, by having the default value of `b` be `Optional.empty()` as well as preventing `null` being passed to the `setB(...)` method, it means `b` can never be `null` which should always be the case anyway in order to leverage the `Optional<T>` type.