# OptionalInt as input argument

Tags: java, java-8, option-type

I read [Why should Java 8's Optional not be used in arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31922866/why-should-java-8s-optional-not-be-used-in-arguments) . But what about `Optional(Int|Long|Double)`, are any arguments against usage of them as input argument?

As I understand correctly, they can not be not empty, but with null (the main argument argument against `Optional<X>` in input parameters), but may be there are other reefs? Should I use `OptionalInt` or `Integer` with `null` and not `null` value?

Comment: What does "other reefs" mean in this context?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This idea of not using Optionals as method parameters is not only specific to `Optional<T>` but all type of Optionals.

When you say:

> As I understand correctly, they can not be not empty, but with null
>   (the main argument argument against `Optional<X>` in input parameters)

First and foremost let's just get the terminology correct, when an `Optional<X>` contains a *non-null* reference we say that it's *present* else we say the `Optional<X>` is *empty* or *absent*. you shouldn't say an `Optional<X>` contains *null*.

All Optionals can be empty regardless of whether it's a container for an object of type `T` or primitive types.

for example, if you peek into the [OptionalInt](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/OptionalInt.html) class documentation, it says:

> **A container object which may or may not contain a int value**. If a
>   value is present, isPresent() will return true and getAsInt() will
>   return the value.

Emphasis mine.

When the Optional does not contain an int value then it's an empty Optional.

> Should I use OptionalInt or Integer with null and not null value?

As for using `OptionalInt` or `Integer` really depends on your use
   case.

- Like all Optional's both for a container of type `T` and
  primitive types they're descriptive and enable one to apply different
  type of operations to extract the value if present or do something
  else if absent.
- Any `Integer` field can be assigned the value *null*.
- One can return `null` in any method having `Integer` as the return type.
- `OptionalInt` fields (controversial) should never be assinged `null` as that defeats the whole purpose of using Optional in the first place.
- One should never return `null` in any method having the return type `OptionalInt` again as it defeats the whole purpose of using Optional in the first place.

etc..

Further, some people actually discourage the use of primitive Optionals simply because they lack the `map`, `flatMap`, and `filter` methods.

Essentially, there's no rule to always use Optionals or vice vera, instead pick the API that best fits your needs.

Comment: ...and they don’t have `null`, even if passed that. They are empty and will explode if you attempt to get the value

Comment: I can not understand you `Optional<X>` can be `! isPresent`, `isPresent` but `null`, and `isPresent(` and  `!= null`, but `OptionalInt` can not be `isPresent` and `null`, because of primitve type can not be `null`

Comment: @user1244932 "`Optional<X>` can be `isPresent` but null" -- No it can't. The value of the `Optional`, if present, is non-null. See [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) -- "A container object which may or may not contain a **non-null** value."

Comment: @Aomine no intention what so ever to step on your answers, just adding a bit more info...

Comment: completely fine @Eugene ;), we should have as many helpful answers as possible!.

Answer (score 3):

So there are 3 things to consider, passing an `OptionalInt`, `Integer` or `int` to a method (or having a property in your class of this type).

*Usually* passing an `Integer` is not the best idea, since you would need to check against `null`. Some people actually want that, well mostly for `Boolean` as it can denote 3 states - `unknown/true/false` - I still don't like it (an `enum` is far more suited in this case).

So semantically passing a `null` to a method that accepts an `Integer` could mean - I *don't want this value* to be present. But then, the code providing such a method should be responsible to handle this; a better approach is to have overloaded methods that do not take it as input as such - thus making it clear IMO that this parameter is not mandatory to begin with.

OK, so is passing an `int` better? Yes, sort of. Think ORM (hibernate) for a second; there are cases when a certain property could be either `int` or `Integer` - in this case I favor `Integer`; mainly because `int` has a a default value or `zero` - and I would prefer code to fail with a `NullPointer` instead of keeping stale values: zero could be a perfectly valid business value, but what if we did not mean to put it as `zero`? Of course, this means that the DB and Service Layer needs proper validation, etc - I am not going into these details.

So what about passing a `OptionalInt` to a method that previously was accepting an `Integer`? You would *still* have to check for the presence of it (is it `null`?), you would still have to check if it is empty or not and take according steps. And that usually means that you want different code paths depending on that parameter - in which case something more descriptive must be passed in.  You could still do it, but what if in time, you will need one more condition? `OptionalInt` can't handle that, so a major refactoring would need to take place.

But Optional are awesome as return types. If a method returns an `Integer` how many times have you checked if it's actually null? On the other hand if a method returns `OptionalInt` you *have* to think what to do in case it is missing, because otherwise you can not retrieve it's value: unless `isPresent?` or any other methods like `orElse/orElseGet` etc.

Comment: I think you meant [mainly because int has a a default value of zero] in your fourth paragraph.