# Hibernate JPA : issue with Optional parameter in repository query

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

When executing the code below I have this error :

> org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not determine a type for
>   class: java.util.Optional

```
@Query("Select distinct  new com.myapp.web.rest.dto.AnalyseStockDTO(" +
            "a.lot.id,a.calibre, a.montantHt, l.valorisation, a.nbColis, 0, a.poidsNet, 0," +
            "(s.qteStock * s.lot.emballage.poidsNetStandard), s.qteStock-0, a.nbPieces, s.qteStock, a.prixUnitaire) " +
            "from Annonce a, Stock s, Lot l " +
            "where a.lot.dateArrivee >= :dateDebut and (:dateFin = null or a.lot.dateArrivee<=:dateFin) and a.lot.id not in (select distinct v1.lot.id from Vente v1) " +
            "and a.lot.id = s.lot.id and a.calibre = s.calibre and a.lot.id = l.id " +
            "and s.qteStock>0 ")
List<AnalyseStockDTO> getAnalyseStock(@Param("dateDebut") LocalDate dateDebut, @Param("dateFin") Optional<LocalDate> dateFin);

venteRepository.getAnalyseStock(dateDebut, Optional.ofNullable(dateFin));
```

Do you know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Hibernate doesn't support Optionals this way. Just pass `null` as a parameter and never use comparing by `= null` in your queries. Use `:dateFin IS NULL` clause because NULLs need special treating in database systems.

2) Don't use Optionals as method parameters - Optional wasn't designed for this purpose.
[Why should Java 8's Optional not be used in arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31922866/why-should-java-8s-optional-not-be-used-in-arguments)

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate just does not know how to deal with `Optional`, only simple types can be used as query parameters.

The possibility of having `dateFin` being null is managed at the query level, you simply don't need to use `Optional`:

```
List<AnalyseStockDTO> getAnalyseStock(@Param("dateDebut") LocalDate dateDebut, @Param("dateFin") LocalDate dateFin);
venteRepository.getAnalyseStock(dateDebut, dateFin);
```