# Optional<T> for an input parameter of a method

Tags: java, option-type

I have created a generic interface which is implemented by certain classes. It looks like:

```
public interface KingdomElementService<T> {

  public T findById(Long id);

  public T save(Optional<T> object);

  public void update(T t);

}
```

My IntelliJ yells at save, writing "Optional is used as a parameter.". I understand the logic that it's weird to take in something that may exist and may not. Why I considered to do this is to rewrite some

```
 if(something){
   do();
 }
 else{
 throw new Expression();
 }
```

to

```
something.orElseThrow(Expression::new);
```

Now I am wondering if my solution of using an Optional is an overkill here or not. What do you think? Should I consider changing it back?

Comment: The Optional class doesn't make sense as a parameter

How can you save something that doesn't exist?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31922866/why-should-java-8s-optional-not-be-used-in-arguments

Comment: I know what you mean. As I have written it, my reason of using optional was nothing like that. My object IRL is not nullable. I merely used optional to be able to reduce the 4-line if statement to a 1-line optional statement which does the same.

Comment: i think use `Optional<T>` as a result is more better。

Comment: It's not clear what the `Optional<T> object` is meant to be for in the context of saving. It might be easier to give an answer with more information about that.

Comment: I am not pretty sure what code snippets should I copy to make it cleaner, but the implementations of this interface save <T> values to their own repositories. 
Please write me if I haven't answered your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Java language architects share the sentiment that Optional should be used only as return type.  This is to signify that return type may be `null`.  So care should be taken.

`Optional` as input parameter will require you to always check if the parameter is present, adding some checks.  If you want to add any validations, you can put it without Optional as well . There is no extra value in marking input parameters as Optional.

Also the calling method that passes the parameter to another method accepting Optional will have to wrap the Object and send.  This is an overhead.

I have not considered Edge cases.

EDIT: Changed from 'Java language is quite clear' to something more truthy.

Comment: "quite clear in documentation" please provide a link to the specific documentation which says this. The *language* doesn't even mention `Optional`, because it's defined in the API; the API documentation for [`Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) doesn't say anything about this.

Comment: @AndyTurner It's not documentation, but [Brian Goetz has expressed a similar sentiment here before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26328555/1898563).

Comment: @Michael that answer basically says "don't use it that way because we didn't intend it". I use an old gym card to scrape ice off my car windscreen: I'm pretty sure that it was never intended to be used that way, but it is effective. I hope the analogy is apparent: that answer doesn't really give a concrete reason *not* to use `Optional` in this way.

Comment: @AndyTurner I guess you need to read between the lines a bit. Using Optional as a parameter does not reduce the risk of any errors, it merely adds verbosity.

Comment: @AndyTurner I apologize if that did not come out right.  The official language specification does not mention it.  But the Java language architects have shared this sentiment.

Comment: @AndyTurner I edited it already  :) . thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 3):

Nothing specific against `Optional` but by using this as a parameter, you are forcing all the callers to pass an `Optional` to this method. I would rather use `@Nullable` for this, e.g.:

```
public T save(@Nullable T object);
```

This would mean you will have to write that `if..else` block (or ternary operator) but in my opinion, the complexity of doing that will be far less than forcing your clients to pass an `Optional`.

Also, you can write `Optional.of(object);` as a first line in your method implementation and use it for the rest of the method code if you want to use the same control structure.

Answer (score 1):

When you have a method like  `save(Optional<T> object);`

I still can make a call `save(null);` that's why optional here does not make sense.

You can implement a simple null check in your method

```
void save(T object){
        if(object == null){
            // do smth
        }
    }
```

Or use Optional.ofNullable() inside the method

```
void save(T object){
    Optional.ofNullable(object)
        .map(..)
    .orElseGet(IllegalAccessError::new);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like if you have an instance of `KingdomElementService<T>`, you want callers of `save` to have the choice of passing an instance of T or not. Thus, given some variables:

```
KingdomElementService<T> kes = ... ;
T someT = ... ;
```

Callers can do this:

```
kes.save(Optional.of(someT)); // 1
kes.save(Optional.empty());   // 2
```

This makes things quite inconvenient for callers. Instead, you should modify `KingdomElementService` to provide overloads of the `save` method: one taking an arg and one taking no args:

```
interface KingdomElementService<T> {
    T save(T t);
    T save();
}
```

If you do this, the callers don't have to bother wrapping everything inside an `Optional`:

```
kes.save(someT); // 1
kes.save();      // 2
```

Essentially, `Optional` doesn't help APIs that want to take optional parameters.