# Java 8 code optimization - remove if statements

Tags: java, java-8, functional-programming, option-type

I'm learning some tricks from Java 8. I created a simple list:

```
 private void createData() {
        bottles.add(new Whiskey("Jack Daniels", "PL"));
        bottles.add(new Whiskey("Balentains", "PL"));
        bottles.add(new Whiskey("Balentains", "EN"));
        bottles.add(new Whiskey("Balentains", "EN"));
        bottles.add(new Whiskey("Balentains", "GR"));
        bottles.add(new Whiskey("Balentains", "PL"));
        bottles.add(new Whiskey("Balentains", "GR"));
    }
```

And now I would like to get items from this list by few things. If user give a parameter `origin`, I want to filter this list by `origins`, but when he gave wrong `origin` then he should get empty list and when he won't give `origin` parameter then he should get whole list.

I have a method which filtering items in list:

```
 private Optional<List<Whiskey>> getWhiskeyFromCountry(String origin) {
        final List<Whiskey> whiskies = bottles.stream()
                .filter(b -> b.getOrigin().equals(origin))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        return whiskies.isEmpty() ? Optional.empty() : Optional.of(whiskies);
    }
```

And also a main method which get parameter (or not) and response with result:

```
private void getAll(RoutingContext routingContext) {
        Optional<String> origin = Optional.ofNullable(routingContext.request().params().get("filter"));
        List<Whiskey> result = getWhiskeyFromCountry(origin.orElse("")).orElse(Collections.EMPTY_LIST);

        routingContext.response()
                .putHeader("content-type", "application/json; charset=utf-8")
                .end(Json.encodePrettily(origin.isPresent() ? result : bottles));
    }
```

The problem is that I still use if statemant in last line and I do not want do this. I would like to change this code into clear and functional. I tried to do some magic with Optionals but in the end I got this one and I think it can be do better and simpler. Could you help me? Or maybe this code is good and I do not need to change anything? This question is more about clean code.

Comment: Just return a `List` from the `getWhiskeyFromCountry` method. If the `origin` is wrong, the list will be empty.

Comment: Why not simply return the empty list? Should work as well.

Comment: @AlexR - it is ok, but still I need to check if statement in last line

Comment: in `getAll` method no need to init `origin` as optional

Comment: Why are you trying to avoid if statements?  AN if statement is nice, clear, fast, and maintainable.  Chains of functional code are not, and perform horribly.

Comment: Also, if looking up by origin is something you want to do frequently, a list of whiskeys is the wrong data structure to use.  All your searches are O(n).

Comment: @GabeSechan - sometimes, but building whole code with ifs is not good practise

Comment: @allocer No, there is nothing wrong with usign an if.  I'm not sure where you got the idea that if statements should be avoided, but its absolutely wrong.

Comment: @GabeSechan - I did not say that should be avoided. But I would like to do this code in functional style. Also I think that for example building "if ladders" can be change by functional style

Comment: @allocer Funcitonal has nothing to do with avoiding ifs.  Every functional language in existance has if statements.  You don't understand what functional is.  Functional tries to avoid *state*, not if statements.

Comment: @GabeSechan - yes, but you can also minimalize if statements in the code to get more readability. For example if you want to filter list you use streams which remove a lot of ifs from the code.

Comment: @allocer No, if you're trying to use streams to minimize if statements, you're not understanding streams, funcitonal programming, and making less readable code. You're replacing a nice, easily readable high performing if with a slow, low performance, less readable function call.  This is not something you should be attempting to do.  It's poor style and bad programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make this method `getWhiskeyFromCountry` to accept `Optional<String>` as parameter

```
private List<Whiskey> getWhiskeyFromCountry(Optional<String> origin)
```

and then if Optional is empty return empty list or return list based on `filter`, If user enters the wrong `origin` still you will get the empty list

```
return origin.map(o->bottles.stream()
            .filter(b -> b.getOrigin().equals(o))
            .collect(Collectors.toList())).orElse(Collections.EMPTY_LIST);
```

Or in the above code you can make small tweak to return `List` for this method `getWhiskeyFromCountry`

```
 private List<Whiskey> getWhiskeyFromCountry(String origin) {

    return bottles.stream()
            .filter(b -> b.getOrigin().equals(origin))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
  }
```

And in the main method use `Optional.map`

```
Optional<String> origin = Optional.ofNullable(routingContext.request().params().get("filter"));
List<Whiskey> result = origin.map(o->getWhiskeyFromCountry(o))
                             .orElse(bottles);
```

Comment: Passing `Optional` as parameter is not best practice!

Comment: May i know why @HadiJ ?

Comment: @Deadpool, Although I disagree by getting `origin` as optional, but for your second approach to avoid double checking i think it's better use this `origin.map(o->getWhiskeyFromCountry(o))
                             .orElse(bottles);`

Comment: Or maybe something like this `Optional<String> getParam(RoutingContext routingContext){return Optional.ofNullable(routingContext.request().params().get("filter"));}` and then in `getAll` method `getParam(routingContext).map(o->getWhiskeyFromCountry(o)) .orElse(bottles);`

Comment: For references to what @HadiJ pointed out. [Why should Optional not be used in arguments.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31922866/why-should-java-8s-optional-not-be-used-in-arguments)