# Optional parameters for Request Param is a bad practise?

Tags: java, spring, java-8, option-type

I'm using Optional parameters for my Rest controller, in my case to distinguish which method to call:

```
@GetMapping("/cars")
@ResponseBody
public List<CarsDTO> getAllCarsByCat(@RequestParam Optional<Integer> cat1,
                                     @RequestParam Optional<Integer> cat2) {
    if (cat1.isPresent() && cat2.isPresent())
        return carsService.getAllCarsByCat1AndCat2(cat1.get(), cat2.get());
    else if (cat1.isPresent())
        return carsService.getAllCarsByCat1(cat1.get());
    else if (cat2.isPresent())
        return carsService.getAllCarsByCat2(cat2.get());
    else
        return carsService.getAllCars();

}
```

Why does the highest voted response of the thread below propose that "Using Optional parameters causing conditional logic inside the methods is literally contra-productive."?

[Why should Java 8's Optional not be used in arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31922866/why-should-java-8s-optional-not-be-used-in-arguments)

I do exactly that and consider it as the most readable and straight forward solution. What is bad with this approach?

Comment: The answers to this question will be opinion based and this question can be closed. In my opinion, your code without *Optional* would be more readable / understandable if you had plain *Integer* types: all *if* expressions would be compact, but passing parameters to the *carService* would be even compacter than it is now, because *Optional.get()* would not be needed. In your case *Optional* wrappers are created, but I would neglect related memory and performance effects, which would be an additional contra argument for others.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The only concern using `Optional` as `@RequestParam` is performance and creating Optional wrapper using `Optional.OfNullable` and unwrapping using `Optional.get()` or checking using `Optional.ifPresent()`. As a functional perspective it always looks good using `Optional` but as a good programmer it is an unnecessary additional operations wrapping and unwrapping. In spring `Optional` is allowed in [@RequestParam](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-requestparam) to declare param as optional

> By default, method parameters that use this annotation are required, but you can specify that a method parameter is optional by setting the @RequestParam annotation’s required flag to false or by declaring the argument with an java.util.Optional wrapper.

So you can simply make those `@RequestParam` as optional using `required==false` and follow the same approach using if else, you can also use [Objects.nonNull](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#nonNull-java.lang.Object-) for more readability or you can also use [defaultValue](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestParam.html#defaultValue--)

```
@GetMapping("/cars")
@ResponseBody
 public List<CarsDTO> getAllCarsByCat(@RequestParam(name="cat1", required=false) Integer cat1,
                                 @RequestParam(name="cat2", required=false) Integer cat2) {
     if (cat1!=null && cat2!=null)
         return carsService.getAllCarsByCat1AndCat2(cat1, cat2);
     else if (cat1!=null)
         return carsService.getAllCarsByCat1(cat1);
     else if (cat2!=null)
         return carsService.getAllCarsByCat2(cat2);
     else
         return carsService.getAllCars();

  }
```