# Copy a Guava Optional

Tags: java, guava

Is there a "nice" way to create a copy of an Optional object?

For example, say I have a method

```
Optional<Obj> doSomeStuff(Optional<Obj> input){
   if(something){
     return Optional.copyOf(input); // does this exist in some Guava library or something?
   }
   // ...
}
```

Basically, I want to have immutability so that I don't pass the same Optional around, and if `something` gets triggered then I want to make sure that I create a brand new Optional with same contents of the `input` Optional (whether it be empty or not).

Is there any clean way to do it? The `Optional.copyOf` method does not exist.

Comment: Please see: [the documentation of `Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html), [Why should Java 8's Optional not be used in arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31922866/why-should-java-8s-optional-not-be-used-in-arguments), [Sonar RSPEC-3553](https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/RSPEC-3553)

Comment: @Turing85, assuming that I must (no choice in the current codebase)

Comment: Just in case you did not know, Java has its own `Optional` since Java 8.

Answer (score 7):

The `Optional` class is immutable,  so you do not need copy,. You can just do `return input`.

Answer (score 3):

Guava `Optional` is already immutable.
You don't need to make a copy of it.

Here is the beginning of the javadoc:

> An **immutable** object that may contain a non-null reference to another object. Each instance of this type either contains a non-null reference, or contains nothing (in which case we say that the reference is "absent"); it is never said to "contain null".