# filter a list of optional strings

Tags: java, option-type

Given a method such as

```
public Optional<List<String>> removeShortWords(Optional<List<String>> maybeWords) {
    
}
```

Is there a way to filter out all strings that have fewer than 5 characters?
One way is to unwrap the `Optional`, filter out the short words, and then wrap the result in a new `Optional`:

```
public Optional<List<String>> removeShortWords(Optional<List<String>> maybeWords) {

    if (maybeWords.isPresent()) {
        List<String> words = maybeWords.get();

        List<String> longWords = words.stream()
            .filter(word -> word.length() >= 5)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

        return Optional.of(longWords);
    }

    return maybeWords;
}
```

Surely there must be a simpler solution than this?

Comment: Given this method `Optional<List<String>> removeShortWords(Optional<List<String>> maybeWords)` you should try to refactor it to `List<String> removeShortWords(List<String> maybeWords)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html) provides methods, such as [`Optional#map`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html#map(java.util.function.Function)), that allow you to modify its value if the value is present. You'd be able to use that in your case:

```
public Optional<List<String>> removeShortWords(Optional<List<String>> maybeWords) {
    return maybeWords.map(list -> 
        list.stream().filter(s -> s.length() >= 5).collect(Collectors.toList()));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `map`:

```
public Optional<List<String>> removeShortWords(Optional<List<String>> maybeWords) {
    return maybeWords.map(x -> x.stream().filter(y -> y.length() >= 5)
        .collect(Collectors.toList()));
}
```

However, you should note that `Optional` is designed for method returned types, not for parameters. I would just accept a `List<String>`, since `List<String>` is already nullable. And check for null "normally". See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31922866/why-should-java-8s-optional-not-be-used-in-arguments) for more info.

Comment: Upvoted for the note on `Optional` as (misused) parameter type.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Optional#ifPresent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#ifPresent-java.util.function.Consumer-) and [`Collection#removeIf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeIf-java.util.function.Predicate-).

```
public Optional<List<String>> removeShortWords(Optional<List<String>> maybeWords) {
    maybeWords.ifPresent(list -> list.removeIf(str -> str.length() < 5));
    return maybeWords;
}
```

Comment: This would work if, and only if, the `List` implementation supports removal of elements (unlike the `List` returned by `Arrays.asList`, `List.of`, `Collections.singletonList`, etc.)