# How to check whether Optional value is null and how to pass it to other method?

Tags: java, spring, api, http, option-type

I need to pass `dateTs` from rest controller class-method into `getCars()` method in the service class which will retrieve cars that were registered on the given timestamp date and if the timestamp `dateTs`(its Optional) is null then it will retrieve all cars.
I think current implementation will not work since if `dateTs` is null then it can't be passed into `getCars()` which expects value of type `Long`. Where and how should I check if the `dateTs` is not null and how to pass corresponding value into `getCars()` and invoke appropriate method?

```
@GetMapping(value = "/get/cars")
public CarList CarController(@Param("dateTs") Optional<Long> dateTs) {
   
return ResponseEntity.ok(carService.getCars((Long) dateSt.get());
}
```

Service class method:

```
public List<Car> getCars(Long dateSt) {
   List<Car> carList; 
  
   if(dateSt != null){
       carList = carReposistory.retrieveRegisteredCars(dateSt);}
   else{
      carList = carReposistory.retrieveAllCars();} 
       
   return carList;
}
```

Comment: null can be passed to getCars as Long is an object, you would have a problem with long (native type)

Comment: Not sure what you meant by "long (native type)" ? I have to use `<Long> dateTs`. So you are saying that Long without value attached is still an object. `dateTs` is an optional value  so if no value is provided then I assume Long object without value can be further processed and passed. Will dateSt.get()  cause any issues if its null?

Comment: well I recommed you to read javadocs, https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html for get "If a value is present in this Optional, returns the value, otherwise throws NoSuchElementException.", so yes, you will have an exception thrown as you can see in some answers you can use orElse(null)

Answer (score 3):

Just a note: a `Long` can be `null`, so it can be passed to `getCars(Long)`. It is a `long` that cannot be `null`, since it is a primitive.

The problem probably is that `Optional#get()` throws a `NoSuchElementException` if there is no value in the `Optional` (its value is `null`), you could have used `Optional#orElse()` like in:

```
return ResponseEntity.ok(carService.getCars((Long) dateSt.orElse(null));
```

using `Optional#isPresent()`, as other answer are suggesting, is a (probably better) option.

For reference, check the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html#orElse(T)) of `orElse`.

---

Note 2: also check this question and its answers: [Why should Java 8's Optional not be used in arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31922866/13510609)

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in two way. With passing Optional to `getCars` or without.
With passing:

```
public List<Car> getCars(Optional<Long> dateSt) {
   if(dateSt.isPresent()){
       return carReposistory.retrieveRegisteredCars(dateSt.get());
   }
   return carReposistory.retrieveAllCars(); 
}
```

Without passing: you have to create two separated methods:

```
public List<Car> retrieveRegisteredCars(Long dateSt) {
   return carReposistory.retrieveRegisteredCars(dateSt);
}

public List<Car> retrieveAllCars() {
   return carReposistory.retrieveAllCars(); 
}
```

and use them in controller:

```
return ResponseEntity.ok(
  dateSt.map(carService::retrieveRegisteredCars)
  .orElseGet(() -> carService.retrieveAllCars())
);
```

#### UPDATE

Or just pass null

```
return ResponseEntity.ok(carService.getCars((Long) dateSt.orElse(null)));
```

Answer (score 2):

You usually don't want to pass `Optional`s as parameters, however I don't know if it applies to REST controllers. See [this](http://tion%20in%20thread%20%22main%22%20org.openapitools.codegen.SpecValidationException:%20There%20were%20issues%20with%20the%20specification.%20The%20option%20can%20be%20disabled%20via%20validateSpec%20(Maven/Gradle)%20or%20--skip-validate-spec%20(CLI).)

Now that this is said, you should have two methods in your service, one for when it's present, one when it's absent.

**Controller**

```
@GetMapping(value = "/get/cars")
public CarList CarController(@Param("dateTs") Optional<Long> dateTs) {
    return ResponseEntity.ok(
               dateTs.map(carService::getRegisteredCars)
                     .orElseGet(carService::getAllCars)
           );
}
```

**Service**

```
public List<Car> getRegisteredCars(Long dateSt) {
    return carReposistory.retrieveRegisteredCars(dateSt);
}

public List<Car> getAllCars() {
    return carReposistory.retrieveAllCars();
}
```