# How to manipulate Optional Spring @RequestParam

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, option-type

I'm new to JPA.
I have a class like this

```
@Table(name="student")
@Entity
public class Student{
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int studentId;
    
    @Column
    @Size(max = 20)
    private String name;
    
    @Column
    @Min(value = 2014)
    @Max(value = 2020)
    private int yearOfBirth;
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "classroomId")
    Classroom classroom;

    //Getters and setters
    }
```

My repository:

```
        @Repository
        public interface HocSinhRepository extends JpaRepository<Student, Integer> {}
```

My controller:

```
public class StudentController {
        @Autowired
        StudentRepository studentRepository;
        
        @GetMapping(value = "/get")
        public Page<Student> get(@RequestParam Optional<Integer> page, @RequestParam Optional<String> sortBy) {
            return studentRepository.findAll(
                    PageRequest.of(page.orElse(0), 3, Sort.Direction.ASC, sortBy.orElse("name"))
                    );
        }
    }
```

By using Optional.orElse, I can assign a default value to the sortBy parameter if it's null. How can I do the same thing if the parameter is not null, but just a non-sensible string (like "asdasd")?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `map` operator of optionals.

So it would be

```
sortBy.map(o -> {
           if (o.equalsIgnoreCase("asdasd")){
               return "name";
           } else {
               return o;
           }
       }).orElse("name"));
```

This will make the optional return the value `"name"` when it is empty or when the containing value exists and is with ignore case `"asdasd"`. In every other case it will return the original value it contained.

So your code will be adapted to be

```
return studentRepository.findAll(
                    PageRequest.of(page.orElse(0), 3, Sort.Direction.ASC, 
                                   sortBy.map(o -> {
                                              if (o.equalsIgnoreCase("asdasd")){
                                                   return "name";
                                              } else {
                                                   return o;
                                              }}).orElse("name"));
                   ));
```

Comment: This only works on a specific String. How can I make it work on any String as well?

Answer (score 1):

variation on @xerx593's `VALID_SORT_FIELDS` and making spring's @RequestParam optional

```
    public static final Set<String> VALID_SORT_FIELDS = Set.of("name", "studentId");
    
    @GetMapping(value = "/get")
    public Page<Student> get(
            @RequestParam(required = false, defaultValue = "0") Integer page,
            @RequestParam(required = false, defaultValue = "name") String sortBy) {
        
        String sortByOrDefault = VALID_SORT_FIELDS.contains(sortBy) ? sortBy : "name";
        return studentRepository.findAll(PageRequest.of(page, 3, Sort.Direction.ASC, sortByOrDefault));
    
    }
```

Comment: I notice that making @RequestParam optional is the same as making the parameter type Optional. Is there a distinguishable advantage to either?

Comment: @AnhĐỗ i think Optional is usually [used with return types rather than method arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31922866/why-should-java-8s-optional-not-be-used-in-arguments)

Answer (score 1):

another variation:

```
    @GetMapping(value = "/get")
    public Page<Student> get(
            @RequestParam(required = false, defaultValue = "0") Integer page,
            @RequestParam(required = false, defaultValue = "name") String sortBy) {

        String sortByOrDefault = SortConfig.STUDENTS.getSortableFields().contains(sortBy) 
                ? sortBy
                : SortConfig.STUDENTS.getDefaultSortField();
        return studentRepository.findAll(PageRequest.of(page, 3, Sort.Direction.ASC, sortByOrDefault));

    }

    public enum SortConfig {
        STUDENTS(List.of("name", "studentId")), 
        ANOTHER_ENTITY(List.of("field1", "field2"));

        private String defaultSortField;
        private List<String> sortableFields;

        private SortConfig(List<String> sortableFields) {
            this.sortableFields = sortableFields;
        }

        public String getDefaultSortField() {
            return defaultSortField;
        }

        public List<String> getSortableFields() {
            return sortableFields;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A common scenario would be:

To have the "valid field names" stored in a "data structure", e.g., like:

```
public static final Set<String> VALID_SORT_FIELDS = Set.of("name", "studentId"/*, all we "consider valid"...*/);
```

Then we can use it in our controller like:

```java
@GetMapping(value = "/get")
public Page<Student> get(@RequestParam Optional<Integer> page, @RequestParam Optional<String> sortBy) {
  final String sort = sortBy
  .map( s -> 
      s != null && VALID_SORT_FIELDS.contains(s)?
          s : "name" // or a consatant com.domain.my...DEFAULT_SORT
  )
  .get();
  return studentRepository.findAll(
     PageRequest.of(page.orElse(0), 3, Sort.Direction.ASC, sort)
  );
}
```

When we want to ignore the case, we would adjust to:

```java
...&&  VALID_SORT_FIELDS.contains(s.toLowerCase(/*some (default) Locale*/))
```

---

Another/additional possible approach: validaion-api... but the wrapping Optional is a "challange"(??)...

Comment: If the requirement is this an Enum would be the best approach. No checking should happened then