# Optional<?> as parameter

Tags: java

I have the following methods:

```
Optional<Book> findBook(UUID bookId);

void doSomething(Book book, SomeOtherSutff someOtherStuff);
```

Since it's not recommended to have methods that have an `Optional` as a parameter I'm forced to do this:

```
doSomething(optionalBook.orElse(null), someOtherStuff)
```

The method `parseBook` contains a null check.

This seems wrong but I'm not sure what else can I do.

Example updated.

Thanks

Comment: why is it not recommended to have methods with `Optional` parameters?

Comment: Yes, it's wrong. Use [`Optional.map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) instead.

Comment: What does `parseBook` return if you pass it `null`?

Comment: @thmasker https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31922866/why-should-java-8s-optional-not-be-used-in-arguments

Comment: Do you need to call `parseBook` even if your optional is empty?

Comment: By the way, just because its convention to not use `Optional` for optional parameters, does not necessarily mean that you absolutely have to bend your head around it. There can be valid applications to go against general convention. (This here is not one of them, but still.)

Comment: @kylie.zoltan why do you need to call `parseBook` even if you don't have any `book`? That doesn't make sense and, if actually needed, it may be a better part of the code to make improvements. If there is a "code smell" it's better to fix the issue and not just add a puff of "air freshener"

Comment: @Andrei It's just an example.

Comment: @kylie.zoltan if the example doesn't make sense but you actual use case does then you need to provide a better example. Or describe your situation better, without examples. Otherwise you are limiting the types of answers you will receive.

Comment: There are different opinions about where to use `Optional`. I think Nikolai Parlog [makes a good argument](https://nipafx.dev/stephen-colebourne-java-optional-strict-approach/) why it is a good argument to use `Optional` everywhere, also in parameters. Your example also demonstrates this. I really think you should have `Optional` as the parameters type.

Answer (score 1):

One of the reasons for not using an `Optional<T>` as an input parameter is that you will likely have to construct it on-the-fly just to pass it to that method.

Even if now you have an `Optional<Book>` ready to use, from `findBook`, it may be that future changes to the code will mean the `Optional` is unwrapped and you end up with a naked `Book` you'll have to wrap. That would be annoying, at least.

The solution with unwrapping the `Optional` when calling the `doSomething` method is, I think, the best quick fix available.

Ideally, you want to avoid situations like this from occuring, as they cause confusion and could lead to bugs.

Depending on the semantics, the complexity of your `doSomething` and the importance of the `Book` parameter you could:

1. Create a `doSomething(Book book, SomeOtherSutff someOtherStuff)` and a `doSomething(SomeOtherSutff someOtherStuff)`. This is useful if `doSomething` can be called standalone, without a `Book`, from other parts of the code.
2. Split `doSomething` in three: before doing `Book` things, doing `Book` things and "the rest of the processing". This can have various benefits, especially when processing many items. It may be that instead of doing `(A, B, C), (A, B, C), ..., (A, B, C)` that it's better to do `(A, A, ..., A), (B, B, ..., B), (C, C, ...C)` or `(A, A, ..., A), (B, C), (B, C), ..., (B, C)`
3. Do nothing. It doesn't seem like more than a minor annoyance and making changes will cost time and risk introducing bugs.

Comment: I wouldn't add a check to see if the `Optional` parameter is not `null`. If it is `null` then it is an unrecoverable error. At most I can throw an exception other than a `NPE`, but is that really worth it? Instead, the parameter can be marked as `@NotNull Optional<Book>` and the tooling can warn the developers if they mistakenly pass `null`

Answer (score 0):

With following code you'll only call `parseBook` when `Optional<Book>` isn't empty

```java
BookInfo info = optionalBook
   .map(book -> parseBook(book))
   .orElse(null);
```