# Java. Which @Nullable should I use to mark return value with one?

Tags: java, java-8, sonarqube

My java method can return `null` and non null results. I want mark method with `@Nullable` annotation to make it more readable.

I used `com.sun.istack.internal.Nullable` but sonar says **Classes from "sun.*" packages should not be used. Code smell Major squid:S1191**.

I try to find more similar annotations, but there are variants from different IDE, not from java vendor.

Does java (oracle) provides alternatives for nullable annotation or I should use third party libraries only? If I have to use third party library to have an `@Nullable` which one should be good?

Comment: Use `javax.annotation.Nullable` from [JSR 305](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=305) instead of an internal Sun class. You can find that annotation in for example [com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.google.code.findbugs%7Cjsr305%7C3.0.2%7Cjar)

Comment: you can just return `Optional<T>`

Comment: Relevant/Duplicate : [Can't find @Nullable inside javax.annotation.*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19030954/cant-find-nullable-inside-javax-annotation)

Comment: i promote the comment from @dehasi. just return an optional, this is probably the most readable version

Comment: @Jesper - good idea thanks.

Comment: @dehasi Like it. but the method is private, and it is called from lambda, the result is wrapped with optional

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4963300/which-notnull-java-annotation-should-i-use

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, I think for Sonar you could use edu.umd.cs.findbugs.annotations.*, which are deprecated and advise you to use javax.annotation.Nullable.

I mainly use the Jetbrains ones, https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/nullable-and-notnull-annotations.html, but my main goal is the analysis in IntelliJ.

Answer (score 3):

If you can, consider using `Optional<T>` as the return type to make it more readable. You can express optionality utilizing the type system and benefit from the rich monadic-like API instead of wondering which annotation is the right one.

Answer (score 0):

`Optional<T>` or `@Nullable` or `@return` tag from java-doc are ways to say to users of your API that a method can return `null`. But you mentioned in comments that your method is `private`. It means that nobody, except you, can use it. That's why no additional stuff needed.

Answer (score 0):

With FIndbugs/Spotbugs, use @CheckForNull. See https://sourceforge.net/p/findbugs/bugs/1181)