# Netbeans cannot find symbol class NonNull

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm trying to use @NonNull annotations in my code, but NetBeans won't build it, complaining it cannot find symbol "NonNull". Is there a package I need to import?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't find @Nullable inside javax.annotation.\*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19030954/cant-find-nullable-inside-javax-annotation)

Comment: Those answers though, they seem to concern Maven and Gradle, which I don't believe I'm using?

Comment: You can try importing `org.netbeans.api.annotations.common`, but I can't see why NetBeans doesn't include it's own common annotations package.