# openapi and the javax.annotation.*

Tags: java, annotations, nullable, openapi

You can use this dependency for the @Nullable Annotations

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sourceforge.findbugs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsr305</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.7</version>
</dependency>
```

Or you use the lib from google (see below or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19031259/14129103)):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.code.findbugs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsr305</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: What is the question?