# Using javax.annotation.Nonnull: which java jar dependency to get it from?

Tags: java, spring, kotlin

In our open source constraint solver ([OptaPlanner](https://www.optaplanner.org/)), I want to use `@NonNull` to make it more Kotlin friendly and clearer to use from Java, too.

`spring-core` already uses `@NonNull`, [for example in this code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/lang/NonNull.java#L25). They effectively state for every method parameter if it's nullable or not, [as explained here](https://youtu.be/fBHVYWxCnmA?t=44m8s).

**Which maven/gradle dependency should I use to have the class `javax.annotation.Nonnull` in my classpath?** Which one do the spring guys use? For example, I don't see the findbugs JSR-305 jar [in their dependency list](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-core/spring-core.gradle#L65).

(And can I have it as an optional dependency to avoid bloating my user's classpath?)

Comment: org.springframework.lang.NonNullApi
Should be used at package level in association with org.springframework.lang.Nullable annotations at parameter and return value level.

org.springframework.lang.Nullable
Should be used at parameters, return values and optionally field level in association with NonNullApi package-level annotations.

Comment: I need a neutral jar. I am not going to drag in spring from `optaplanner-core` (only in `optaplanner-spring-boot-starter` which provides seamless integration)

Comment: The following answer suggests that JSR 305 is not the way to go, as it is "Dormant": https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2289694/what-is-the-status-of-jsr-305

Answer (score 7):

I would say that https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.findbugs/jsr305 should be your artifact of choice for this, as it's probably the most commonly used and properly maintained.

Comment: Looks like findbugs in dead, replaced by spotbugs (by the community), which decided to no longer include those annotations: https://github.com/spotbugs/spotbugs/pull/180

Comment: I would disagree that findbugs is properly maintained

Comment: I would like to have a guide to how to install it. What to download, where to put it, how to make it work.