# Can IntelliJ auto-generate code to null-check arguments when using @ParametersAreNonnullByDefault annotation on package

Tags: java, intellij-idea, annotations, findbugs, null-check

I like the feature where IntelliJ can automatically generate code to check *at runtime* for null on each argument/parameter passed to a method.

This feature is enabled in `Preferences` > `Build, Execution, Deployment` > `Compiler` > `Add runtime assertions for notnull-annotated methods and parameters` (checkbox). The neighboring `Configure annotations` button configures which annotation package.

I am trying to set my not-null annotation at the package level. Example:

```
@ParametersAreNonnullByDefault
package work.basil.ticktock.backend.data;

import javax.annotation.ParametersAreNonnullByDefault;
```

My question is: Which, if any, of these "Configure annotations" work the generate code for the `@ParametersAreNonnullByDefault` annotation [discussed here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/parametersarenonnullbydefault-annotation.html) and [found here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.findbugs/jsr305)?

The null-checks are indeed working *within the code editor*, generating warnings. But I want runtime-checking as provided by the checkbox shown in this screenshot.

[image: Screenshot of IntelliJ Preferences > Build, Execution, Deployment > Compiler > Add runtime assertions for notnull-annotated methods and parameters (checkbox)]

Comment: Related: [*Set findbugs NotNull as default for all classes under a package*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13310994/642706)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please follow/comment the duplicated feature request already created at YouTrack, but not yet implemented: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-164347. Thank you.