Hazelcast and javax.annotation.* compatability issues while spring upgarde 3.2.4
I have been working on springboot 3.2.4 upgrades where javax.* namespaces have been shifted to jakarta.* namespaces. I see that in the latest Hazelcast 5.4.0 version they have upgraded javax.jms.* to jakarta. As per springboot dependencies in maven, it expects jakarta.annotation-api. But I see in the latest Hazelcast 5.4.0 version, it still uses javax.annotion.* (javax.annotion.NotNUll) dependencies. Will it cause compatability issues further on?

I am referring to javax.annotation.NotNull which is coming from jsr305 jar

JSR305 is not part of Jakarta EE nor Java SE :) See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2289694/what-is-the-status-of-jsr-305

If you are talking about this dependency for javax.annotation-api
https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/blob/master/hazelcast-spring/pom.xml#L117
Then it is redundant and harmless because there is no direct usage of jakarta.annotation.* package in hazelcast-spring module. Also the scope of the dependency is provided so it should not cause any problem for you
The javax.annotation-api dependency should be removed though in my opinion.
